# ¿Qué campo elegir para la clave primaria?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, diseño

A la hora de declarar la clave primaria (PK) de una tabla (p.e. USUARIO), hay varias opciones:

- Se puede colocar un campo existente (`username`) como clave primaria (clave natural), así el nombre de usuario será validado para que no haya ningún otro igual. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    username VARCHAR(30) not null;
    password VARCHAR(30) not null;
    tipo_u   VARCHAR(10) null;

    PRIMARY KEY(username)
  ) ENGINE INNODB
  ```
- Se puede añadir un nuevo campo (`iduser`) como clave primaria (clave subrogada), tal vez auto incremental si se desea. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    iduser   INT not null AUTO_INCREMENT;
    username VARCHAR(30) not null;
    password VARCHAR(30) not null;
    tipo_u   VARCHAR(10) null;

    PRIMARY KEY(iduser)
  ) ENGINE INNODB
  ```

¿Es alguna de las dos más recomendable? ¿Cuál de las dos maneras permite un mejor funcionamiento en una base de datos? ¿Qué ventajas trae cada método?

¿Es más seguro usando el iduser? Yo en realidad no le veo mucha utilidad pero si he visto que muchos sitios lo usan así.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta tiene potencial para ser muy buena y servir a muchos usuarios si se edita y se hace algo más genérica. ¿Te importa si la edito? Si no te gusta siempre podemos volver a la versión original.

Comment: No hay problema.  Será genial que ayude a mas personas!

Comment: La he cambiado para hacerla algo más genérica. Creo que he mantenido la idea original sin problemas, pero mírala y dime si está bien

Comment: Me parece bien, aunque el uso de la palabra subrogadas me parece algo fuerte y difícil de tragar, entiendo que es el término correcto,  pero si algun nuevo lo lee puede que le pese un poco la palabra.  ¿Hay algun sinónimo para esta? Para así hacerla un poco mas amigable a los que estamos aprendiendo .. ¿tu que opinas?

Comment: OK. Se puede eliminar, ¿qué te parece quitarlo del título pero lo mantenerlo en el cuerpo? (porque se podría encontrar la pregunta buscando por ese término y es el nombre técnico). ¿Qué tal algo más como "¿Qué campo elegir para la clave primaria?" para el título?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) El username no puede ser auto incremental, teniendo en cuenta que es un `varchar` y que el username sera introducido a través del formulario.

2) El username puedes ponerlo como `PRIMARY KEY` o como `UNIQUE`

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    usuario1 varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    usuario2 varchar(30) UNIQUE
    );
```

La ventaja de utilizar un id de tipo int se ve a la hora de crear relaciones con otras tablas. Además te facilita la búsqueda de multiples usuarios.

Por Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id BETWEEN 100 AND 500;
```

Algo que no puedes hacer con usuario `varchar(30)`.

Lo recomendado es utilizar ambos. PRIMARY KEY para el iduser y UNIQUE para username

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
iduser   INT not null AUTO_INCREMENT;
username VARCHAR(30) not null UNIQUE;
password VARCHAR(30) not null;
tipo_u   VARCHAR(10) null;

PRIMARY KEY(iduser)
)ENGINE INNODB
```

Fijate que `username` esta como `UNIQUE` Esto impide que se repita el nombre de usuario. La ventaja de UNIQUE es que puedes tener varios campos `UNIQUE` en la misma tabla a diferencia de `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: OOOHH YA VEO!!! Gracias Jesse me haz aclarado un monton.. incluso con lo de UNIQUE ahora si le veo utilidad! Entonces el id sirve para facilitar las consultas mas adelante al ser un Numero ... ya veo... oooh.. jaja ahora si seguire este metodo creo que es el mas adecuado! Creo que con esto puedo cerrar esta pregunta.

Comment: Jeje primera vez que hago esto.. ya lo hice! Gracias por tu ayuda! me haz aclarado un monton!

Comment: Quizás no se podría utilizar `BETWEEN` como en ese ejemplo, pero sí que se podrían buscar múltiples usuarios con un `varchar(30)` usando otros operadores como `IN` o `LIKE`.

Comment: lo mismo puedes hacer con `username varchar(30) UNIQUE`

Answer (score 16):

Realmente la manera que elijas va a depender del diseño que quieras hacer en tu base de datos.

El tema de añadir un ID numérico autoincremental a las tablas (clave subrogada) en lugar de usar campos ya existentes (clave natural) es un tema que se ha debatido mucho, y que tiene partidarios y detractores porque los dos métodos tienen sus ventajas e inconvenientes.

Vamos a ver algunas ventajas e inconvenientes de los dos casos:

### Claves subrogadas <sup>(añadir un iduser autoincremental)</sup>

Ventajas:

- **Flexibles**: la lógica de operaciones ya no estará en las claves, lo cual te va a permitir hacer cambios en campos que usando claves naturales no podrías (o que sería peor que un dolor de muelas).
- **Ligeras/Espacio**: aunque inicialmente estás añadiendo más peso a la tabla (ver abajo), conforme crece la base de datos (y tienes más claves foráneas) te estarás ahorrando espacio.
- **Unicidad y uniformidad**: mueves la complejidad de crear IDs únicos a la base de datos, que tiene mecanismos rápidos y seguros para imponerlos y seguirían el mismo criterio.

Inconvenientes:

- **Normalización**: las tablas no están completamente normalizadas porque al añadir un campo adicional (y realmente innecesario para identificar una fila) hay varias claves candidatas.
- **Espacio**: Ocupa más espacio en la tabla inicial (`int` son 4 bytes)... aunque esto suele verse compensado por el espacio que se salva luego (ver arriba).
- **Complejidad**: añaden algo de complejidad porque donde antes podías hacer un simple `SELECT` ahora tendrás que añadir más campos y joins con las tablas hijas.

### Claves naturales <sup>(utilizar username como clave)</sup>

Ventajas:

- **Comprensibles**: son fáciles de leer y entender. Aunque ojo: ésta es una ventaja para humanos, a la base de datos no le importa que tu `SELECT`sea legible mientras sea válida.
- **Espacio**: no se añade un nuevo campo a la tabla, ahorrándote unos cuantos bytes por fila en cada tabla que uses claves naturales (aunque a largo plazo no funciona).
- **Simplicidad**: si sabes el username, podrías buscar en otras tablas por ese valor. Mientras que con una clave subrogada tendrías que hacer JOIN con la tabla de usuarios para obtener el ID.

Inconvenientes:

- **Velocidad**: Estás usando cadenas, las comparaciones y JOINs son más lentas que con tipos numéricos y ocupan más espacio.
- **Poco flexibles**: la clave es la lógica de operaciones/negocio, si por cualquier motivo quieres cambiarla, tendrías que cambiar todas las tablas, lo cual será un proceso costoso.
- **Complejidad**: depende de cómo implementes las claves y su unicidad, estarías llevando la complejidad de la base de datos a tu programa.

---

Como en todo, va a haber gente que se decida por una o por la otra. En lo personal, prefiero claves subrogadas porque, por mi experiencia pasada, me resultan más flexibles y ocupan bastante menos espacio conforme crece la base de datos.

Voy a ponerte dos ejemplos que me he encontrado en el pasado, aplicados a tu caso:

**Claves subrogadas ocupando menos espacio**

En tu caso, userid sería un `int` que ocupa 4 bytes y username sería un `varchar(30)` que puede ocupar hasta 31 bytes (1 para el tamaño + 30 por caracteres).

Si añades userid, estarías añadiendo 4 bytes más a la tabla original, pero en cada fila que se utilice como clave foránea en otra tabla te estarías ahorrando 27 bytes (31-4) en el peor de los casos (y en informática siempre hay que ponerse en el peor caso).

Eso quiere decir que en cuanto tengas cad userid como clave foránea en una tabla, ya te habrías ahorrado el peso añadido en la tabla inicial.

**Clave subrogadas siendo más flexibles**

Imagina que tienes una base de datos con docenas de tablas y miles (o millones) de registros, muchas de ellas relacionadas con usuarios y con userid/username como clave foránea. Y ahora imagina que tienes que el usuario decide que quiere cambiar su username (pasa). ¿Qué ocurre?

- Con userid es un proceso trivial: cambias el username en la tabla de usuarios y proceso terminado.
- Con username la cosa se complica: tienes que ir tabla por tabla actualizando campos y claves foráneas. Con un poco de suerte, tienes la base bien definida y todo funciona bien y tu `ON UPDATE CASCADE` hace el trabajo por ti... pero ese no siempre es el caso.

Y un ejemplo cercano: Stack Overflow permite cambiar tu nombre de usuario una vez al mes (creo). Y tienen un sistema de clave userid (el tuyo es 34527) como clave primaria y luego el username como un campo aparte que es más sencillo de cambiar para ellos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación Alvaro! Interesante ejemplo el que das jeje :)

Comment: +1, esta es la respuesta más completa

Answer (score 3):

A decir verdad no hay diferencia a nivel de Base de Datos con respecto al rendimiento en ella en las dos formas que expones, ya que en las consultas SQL prioriza las columnas que tengan índices, mas aún si es un índice de clave primaria. Es decir:

Si la columna **username** es PK de la tabla su **where** se ve priorizado, mientras que userFecCreacion al no ser una columna con índice no.

```
Where username = 'usuario' and userFecCreacion = Getdate();
```

Lo que puedo acotar es que en el primer caso que presentas, username VARCHAR(30), no sería optimo, ya que el tipo no ayuda, en vez de Varchar (al ser variable el campo) utilizaría Char. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Rostan aunque no entendi muy bien algunas cosas jeje :s ..

Comment: Con gusto puedo aclarártelas, solo formula la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu disposición, Eso de que "su where se ve priorizado", no capto la idea.

Comment: SQL al momento de revisar las clausulas del where, priorizara aquellas donde la columna condicionada pertenezca al índice de la tabla. Como por ejemplo cuando haces un where sobre la columna del primary key.

Comment: "_no hay diferencia a nivel de Base de Datos con respecto al rendimiento_" no es del todo cierto. Un `int` en principio ocuparía menos espacio que un `varchar(30)` y ahora ponte a multiplicar cuántas veces va eso como clave foránea.

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar identity esto lo hara unico y auto incrementado

CREATE TABLE usuarios(
iduser   INT identity;
username VARCHAR(30) not null UNIQUE;
password VARCHAR(30) not null;
tipo_u   VARCHAR(10) null;

PRIMARY KEY(iduser)
)