# ¿Llave primaria compuesta no auto incremental o llave primaria simple no auto incremental en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura:

```
CAMPO           TIPO                        NULL    KEY     DEAFULT     EXTRA
id_laudes       int(11)                     NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment
id_liturgia     int(11)                     NO      UNI     NULL    
la_himno        int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO      MUL     NULL    
la_salmos       int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO              NULL    
la_biblica      int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO              NULL    
la_benedictus   int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO              NULL    
la_preces       int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO              NULL    
la_oracion      int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO              NULL
```

La información de índices muestra lo siguiente:

```
Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name     Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed      Index_type  
PRIMARY         1           id_laudes       A           241         NULL        NULL        BTREE       
unique_index    1           la_himno        A           120         NULL        NULL        BTREE       
unique_index    2           la_salmos       A           241         NULL        NULL        BTREE       
unique_index    3           la_biblica      A           241         NULL        NULL        BTREE       
unique_index    5           la_benedictus   A           241         NULL        NULL        BTREE       
unique_index    6           la_preces       A           241         NULL        NULL        BTREE       
unique_index    7           la_oracion      A           241         NULL        NULL        BTREE       
id_liturgia     1           id_liturgia     A           241         NULL        NULL        BTREE
```

- la columna `id_laudes` es la llave primaria, autoincremental.
- la columna `id_liturgia` es un índice único
- las demás columnas forman parte de un índice múltiple

### La duda

La columna `id_laudes`, auto incremental que hace de llave primaria no se relaciona con ninguna otra tabla. Por su parte, la columna `id_liturgia` no podrá estar repetida más de una vez en la tabla, por tanto, ella podría ser una buena candidata a llave primaria, pero no podría ser auto incremental, ya que esa columna la uso para relacionar con otra tabla de la base de datos.

Por otra parte, todas las columnas de la tabla, menos `id_laudes` podrían conformar un índice único, ya que en la tabla no se podrá repetir nunca un registro que tenga los mismos valores en todas esas columnas.

También, todas las columnas, menos `id_laudes` se relacionan cada una con otra tabla de la base de datos.

Creo que podría prescindir de `id_laudes`. Pero dudo sobre si :

- **¿La llave primaria (debe y/o puede ser) `id_liturgia`, tomando en cuenta que no sería auto incremental?. ¿En ese caso sería mejor un índice único combinado con las demás columnas o un índice por cada una?**
- **¿O bien puedo tener una llave primaria compuesta que combine todas las columnas de la tabla?**

En realidad no sé cual sería la mejor opción, tomando en cuenta las relaciones de cada columna con las otras tablas.

**P. D.:**

Para arrojar más luz sobre el problema, esta sería la consulta de la tabla `laudes`, en la que se puede ver cómo se relaciona cada columna de esta tabla con sus respectivas tablas:

```
SELECT  
        l.id_tiempo, lc.cod_liturgia, ls.santo, lsv.vida, lha.antifona_i, lhh.himno, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhsg.orden, '') ORDER BY  id_salmos  SEPARATOR '|') AS ordenes, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhsa.antifonas, '') ORDER BY  id_salmos SEPARATOR '|') AS antifonas, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhs.salmo_ref, '') ORDER BY  id_salmos SEPARATOR '|') AS salmos_ref, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhst.tema, '') ORDER BY  id_salmos SEPARATOR '|') AS temas, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhsi.intro, '') ORDER BY  id_salmos SEPARATOR '|') AS intros, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhsg.parte, '') ORDER BY  id_salmos SEPARATOR '|') AS partes, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhs.salmo, '') ORDER BY  id_salmos SEPARATOR '|') AS salmos,  
        lhlb.ref, lhlb.biblica, biblica_resp, id_forma, antifona_ce, preces_intro, preces, lo.oracion,lh.la_salmos

    FROM liturgia_calendario lc     
    JOIN liturgia l ON lc.id_liturgia=l.id_celebracion 
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_2 lh ON l.id_celebracion=lh.id_liturgia    
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_1 lh1 ON lc.id_liturgia=lh1.id_liturgia
    LEFT OUTER JOIN liturgia_santos ls ON lc.id_liturgia=ls.id_liturgia 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN liturgia_horas_santos_vidas lsv ON lsv.id_santo=ls.id_santo 
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_antifonas_join lhaj ON lh1.ol_antifona=lhaj.id_liturgia 
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_antifonas lha ON lhaj.id_antifona=lha.id_antifona 
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_himnos_join lhhj ON lh.la_himno=lhhj.id_liturgia
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_himnos lhh ON lhhj.id_himno=lhh.id_himno 
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_salmos_grupos lhsg ON lh.la_salmos=lhsg.id_liturgia 
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_salmos_antifonas lhsa ON lhsg.id_antifonas=lhsa.id_antifonas
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_salmos_temas lhst ON lhsg.id_tema=lhst.id_tema
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_salmos_intros lhsi ON lhsg.id_intro=lhsi.id_intro
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_salmos lhs ON lhsg.id_salmo=lhs.id_salmo 
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_lbiblicas_join lhlbg ON lh.la_biblica=lhlbg.id_liturgia
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_lbiblicas_breves lhlb ON lhlbg.id_biblica=lhlb.id_biblica
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_lbiblicas_responsorios lhlbr ON lhlbg.id_responsorio=lhlbr.id_responsorio
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_ce_join lhcej ON lh.la_benedictus=lhcej.id_liturgia 
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_ce lhce ON lhcej.id_antifonace=lhce.id_antifonace
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_preces_join lhpj  ON lh.la_preces=lhpj.id_liturgia     
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_preces lhp  ON lhpj.id_preces=lhp.id_preces    
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_horas_oraciones_join lhoj ON lh.la_oracion=lhoj.id_liturgia
    LEFT JOIN liturgia_oraciones lo ON lhoj.id_oracion=lo.id_oracion 

    WHERE       lc.f_yy=:fyy    AND lc.f_mm=:fmm AND lc.f_dd=:fdd
```

Comment: Yo me haría las siguientes preguntas ¿Por que no puede ser `id_liturgia` la clave principal? ¿Que tiene de malo que no sea autoincremental? Si quisiera borrar u actualizar el registro, ¿cuantos datos requiero para hacerlo? Si planeas hacer `JOINs` con esta tabla, los indices combinados son una buena opción para optimizar la consulta. PD: La respuesta a la ultima pregunta es **SI**, pero antes me plantearía ¿que beneficio obtendría al hacer una clave primaria combinando todas las columnas?

Comment: Gracias @Marcos. Efectivamente, se hará `JOINS` con cada una de esas columnas y sus tablas respectivas. Según mis conocimientos la llave primaria combinada me ahorraría el índice múltiple,  o sea, tendría sólo la llave primaria como índice, no sé si esto sea bueno o no, esa es una de las dudas.

Comment: ¿Has visto [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/84599/250)? No es exactamente lo mismo, pero trata un tema parecido.

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro las respuestas a esa pregunta me confirmaron algunas dudas que tenía. El único problema es que la tabla de la que hablo aquí es una especia de tabla intermedia, por lo que no le veo mucho interés a una PK autoincremental. Las columnas que interesan realmente son todas las otras, cada una de las cuales es llave primaria en otra tabla. (Ver consulta al final de mi pregunta editada). En discusión con gbianchi le decía que, aunque estas columnas podrían estar en una tabla genérica `liturgia` quise separarla en tablas más pequeñas para no tener 50 columnas más en `liturgia`

Comment: las llaves compuestas generalmente se usan con base de datos multitenant y tambien tienen un id autoincrementable(el cual es unico) el ejemplo basico es que tienes un sistema que maneja varias empresas y a su vez varias facturas ; con llaves compuestas es la solucion

Answer (score 2):

Las llaves primarias compuestas han caído en deshuso, ya que para sistemas muy grandes, tendrías que llevarte la llave primaria compuesta a todas las tablas relacionadas. Es decir, si la llave primaria compuesta consta de 6 campos y tienes 40 tablas relacionadas a ella tendrías que repetir la inserción, actualizado, borrado o consulta de esos 6 campos en las 40 tablas, eso no es practico.

Por lo tanto yo recomiendo `id_laudes` como llave primaria auto incremental y `id_liturgia` como `unique`. Ademas las operaciones de busqueda en llaves primarias compuestas son mas costosas si hay sobre todo campos no numéricos en la llave. Por otro lado las operaciones de búsqueda a llaves de tipo entero son mucho menos costosas y mas rápidas.

**Actualización:**

Esta es mi idea que aplico paro un sistema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y por qué no `id_liturgia` como llave primaria, puesto que no debería repetirse? Mi duda viene además porque necesito índices en todas las demás columnas, ya que funcionarían como llaves foráneas de otras tablas. Sugiero que veas la pregunta editada, he puesto la consulta que tendría que sacar partiendo de esta tabla, quizá se entienda un poco más la complejidad del problema viendo la consulta. Como le comentaba @gbianchi, a veces tendremos varios elementos y sub_elementos relacionados, sólo que cada elemento reside en su tabla propia, como debe ser, un caso de ejemplo es el de `salmos`.

Comment: El añadir `id_liturgia` como llave primaria ocasionara que en ocasiones tengas llaves que no puedes ingresar, eso lo vera el usuario y generará la sensación de que el sistema no funciona. Ademas de que implicará desarrollos adicionales y muy frecuentes para que se logran manejar los folios correctamente. Pero de la manera como aparece en la imagen todo esto es transparente al usuario. Y facilitas los joins ya que en las clausulas `on` habrá pocos campos comparados con los muchos de la llave compuesta. Ahora los joins tal vez sean a mas tablas, pero es mas manejable.

Comment: La cantidad de `JOINS` es inevitable, porque la liturgia de laudes tiene cerca de 15 elementos distintos almacenados cada uno en su respectiva tabla, por tanto tendré que hacer `JOIN` con cada una de esas tablas. También, es una bd _cerrada_, es decir, el único que ingresa o modifica datos soy yo. En realidad se trata de lo que podríamos llamar un modelo de datos que, cuando esté terminado, será fijo, no es algo para actualizar en un futuro y si algo tuviera que cambiar sería el contenido de alguna tabla, no las relaciones establecidas.

Comment: Pues entonces, ya esta, tu decides si te conviene o no lo propuesto.

Answer (score 1):

Analicemos la tabla, sin saber el contexto de datos, que puede ser realmente muy importante, sobre todo mas que para como guardar los datos, como recuperarlos.

Por lo que se ve de la tabla, tener una llave primaria que es uno a uno con una clave unica es un desproposito. De que serviria??

- No sirve como clave de busqueda, la clave unica ya es de busqueda
- No sirve para unir con otras tablas, dejaste en claro que la que une es la clave única.

Entonces solo esta ocupando espacio, o ahorrando porque es un autoincremental. Pero en ese caso, que nos ahorra???

El sistema que consulte esta tabla y quiera relacionarla con otras, no le interesa la clave autoincremental para nada.

Hasta ahora, no hay un solo motivo por que guardarla, entonces no tiene sentido de existencia.

Eso nos deja la tabla:

<strike>id_laudes       int(11)                     NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment</strike>

```
id_liturgia     int(11)                     NO      PRI     NULL    
la_himno        int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO      MUL     NULL    
la_salmos       int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO              NULL    
la_biblica      int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO              NULL    
la_benedictus   int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO              NULL    
la_preces       int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO              NULL    
la_oracion      int(10) unsigned zerofill   NO              NULL
```

La clave id_liturgia no es autoincremental, supongo que porque la das de alta cuando generas la liturgia. Ve mi nota de mas abajo, de si no debería estar todo en la tabla esa (y estoy asumiendo tu modelo). Igual mas allá de eso, si ya hay una tabla que crea ese id, no habría problema en replicarlo a esta tabla.

Por lo que se entiende de tu pregunta, esta es una tabla pivotante. Se podría generar un indice múltiple por todas las columnas, lo que haría repetir los datos de la tabla por lo menos dos veces para generar el indice. No lo veo mal, no se si sera performante con muchos datos (y la palabra muchos es relativa a hardware y otras cuestiones del sistema).
Pero la idea del indice es controlar solo las repeticiones? yo no soy de tirarle problemas de negocios a la base de datos (por mas que te deja). Pero en este caso, tal vez habria que analizar la cantidad de claves (id) de cada una de las tablas relacionadas, y en caso de querer sacar ese problema de la BD, hacer una clave reducida a los ID mas densos. (por ejemplo si el campo la_oracion, tuviera solo 7 claves y la_himno 700, indexar por la_himno es una buena idea, ya que despues un full scan del resultado serian en el peor de los casos 7 registros).

NOTA: Yo no se si hubiera armado esta tabla como pivotante, porque no dejar estos datos en la misma tabla que id_liturgia? Si al fin al cabo, la relación es 1 a 1 entre la liturgia y cada una de sus partes.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65482/discussion-on-answer-by-gbianchi-llave-primaria-compuesta-no-auto-incremental-o).