# ¿Cómo relacionar proveedores con la tabla producto MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Mi proyecto requiere tener múltiples proveedores para cada producto

Tengo una tabla **producto**

- id
- nombre
- proveedores

La tabla **proveedor** es

- id
- nombre
- direccion

También creé una tabla puente llamada **proveedores** con lo siguiente:

- productoID
- proveedorID

En la tabla puente creo varios registros con el mismo **productoID** y diferente **proveedorID**, ¿es esta la mejor manera de hacerlo?   ¿Cómo puedo hacer que al borrar el producto se borren sus hijos de la tabla puente?

Gracias por ayudarme :D

Comment: [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](http://rextester.com/EQY74433) que se aproxima a tu planteamiento. Las restricciones son indicadas en el `CREATE TABLE` (`ON DELETE CASCADE`)... también puedes dar indicaciones de lo que deba ocurrir cuando se actualiza la tabla (`ON UPDATE...`). A esto se le llama _integridad referencial_. Una nota importante, la base de datos debe ser `InnoDB`, pues si es `MyISAM` no podrás aplicar relaciones de llave primaria-foránea, ni restricciones de integridad referencial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has planteado bien el diseño de tus tablas. Si el mismo producto puede tener varios proveedores, para no tener filas/columnas repetidas en la tabla `productos`, de este modo:

```
tabla_productos

producto_id    producto_nom     proveedor_id
1              Producto1        1
1              Producto1        2
1              Producto1        N...
```

Lo que se suele hacer delegar la relación en una tercera tabla que nos evitará tener innecesariamente filas/columnas repetidas como se muestra más arriba.

Dicha tabla tendrá entonces dos o tres columnas. Llamemos a esa tercera tabla
 **`productos_proveedores`**. Es como si sacásemos de la tabla `productos` la columna *problemática*, es decir, aquella que nos obliga a repetir filas/columnas, trayéndola a esta nueva tabla:

```
id      producto_id     proveedor_id
1       1               1
2       1               2
```

Hay dos cosas a tener en cuenta en esta tabla:

1. **Hay que seguir evitando datos redundantes.** En `productos_proveedores`  no puede haber un mismo producto con un mismo proveedor dos veces. Entonces tendremos que optar por `a`  o por `b`:

   a. Crear un índice único que abarque las columnas `producto_id` y `proveedor_id`. En ese caso tendremos una columna `id` auto_incremental que será la llave primaria.

   O bien,

   b. Creamos una llave primaria combinada usando las columnas `producto_id` y `proveedor_id`.

   Tengo un dilema personal entre `a` o `b`. De hecho, [plantée una pregunta con recompensa incluida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/101058/29967) y todavía no me queda claro. En mi caso son relaciones más complicadas. Tu caso creo que se podrá resolver optando por el modelo `a`, de hecho, así he planteado el código de prueba (más abajo).
2. Tenemos que indicar **lo que ocurrirá cuando se elimine o se actualice un registro** en la tabla `productos` o en la tabla `proveedores`. Es decir, tenemos que dar las indicaciones sobre la *integridad referencial*.

> Nota: Esto sólo es posible si las tablas son creadas usando el engine
>   `InnoDB`, ya que MyISAM no maneja este tipo de relaciones.

Las restricciones, tanto de llaves primarias-foráneas, se indican generalmente al momento de crear la tabla (`CREATE TABLE`). Las relativas a integridad referencial hay que indicarlas explícitamente, ya que MySQL no las deduce basándose en las llaves primarias-foráneas indicadas. Si no se crean durante el `CREATE TABLE` se pueden modificar posteriormente mediante `ALTER TABLE`. La documentación explica cómo hacerlo.

Existen dos tipos de restricciones: `ON DELETE` y `ON UPDATE`. Y dentro de ellas a su vez varias posibilidades (es lo mismo para ambas).

Vamos a explicarlo con la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

Para los motores de almacenamiento que admiten claves foráneas, MySQL rechaza cualquier operación `INSERT` o `UPDATE` que intente crear un valor de clave externa en una tabla secundaria si no hay un valor de clave candidata coincidente en la tabla primaria.

Cuando una operación `UPDATE` o `DELETE` afecta a un valor de clave en la tabla principal que tiene filas coincidentes en la tabla secundaria, el resultado depende de la acción referencial especificada utilizando las subcláusulas `ON UPDATE` y `ON DELETE` de la cláusula `FOREIGN KEY`. MySQL admite cinco opciones con respecto a la acción que se va a tomar:

- `CASCADE`: Elimine o actualice la fila de la tabla principal y elimine o actualice automáticamente las filas coincidentes en la tabla secundaria. Tanto `ON DELETE CASCADE` como `ON UPDATE CASCADE` son compatibles. Entre dos tablas, no se definen varias cláusulas `ON UPDATE CASCADE` que actúan en la misma columna en la tabla primaria o en la tabla secundaria.

Nota
Las acciones de clave externa en cascada no activan activadores.

- `SET NULL`: Elimine o actualice la fila de la tabla principal y establezca la columna o columnas de clave externa en la tabla secundaria en `NULL`. Se admiten las cláusulas `ON DELETE SET NULL` y `ON UPDATE SET NULL`.

Si especifica una acción `SET NULL`, asegúrese de que no ha declarado las columnas de la tabla secundaria como `NOT NULL`.

- `RESTRICT`: Rechaza la operación de eliminación o actualización para la tabla padre. Especificar `RESTRICT` (o `NO ACTION`) es lo mismo que omitir la cláusula `ON DELETE` o `ON UPDATE`.
- `NO ACTION`: Una palabra clave del SQL estándar. En MySQL, equivalente a `RESTRICT`. El servidor MySQL rechaza la operación de eliminación o actualización para la tabla primaria si hay un valor de clave externa relacionado en la tabla referenciada. Algunos sistemas de base de datos tienen cheques diferidos, y `NO ACTION` es un cheque diferido. En MySQL, las restricciones de clave externa se comprueban inmediatamente, por lo que `NO ACTION` es igual que `RESTRICT`.
- `SET DEFAULT`: Esta acción es reconocida por el analizador de MySQL, pero tanto InnoDB como NDB rechazan las definiciones de tablas que contienen cláusulas `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` o `ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT`.

Para una `ON DELETE` o `ON UPDATE` que no se especifica, la acción predeterminada es siempre `RESTRICT`.

MySQL admite referencias de clave externa entre una columna y otra dentro de una tabla. (Una columna no puede tener una referencia de clave externa a sí misma.) En estos casos, "registros de tabla secundaria" se refiere realmente a registros dependientes dentro de la misma tabla.

Una restricción de clave externa en una columna generada almacenada no puede utilizar `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, `ON DELETE SET NULL`, `ON UPDATE SET NULL`, `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` o `ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT`.

Una restricción de clave externa no puede hacer referencia a una columna generada virtual.

Para las restricciones de InnoDB relacionadas con claves externas y columnas generadas, consulte la [Sección 14.8.1.6, "Restricciones de InnoDB y FOREIGN KEY"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

---

### Prueba con datos reales

**<kbd>[`VER DEMO`](http://rextester.com/AMUMG33384)</kbd>**

Puedes modificar el código del DEMO para verificar cómo funciona la integridad referencial según sus diversas posibilidades.

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proveedores_20170917 
(
    proveedor_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    proveedor_nom VARCHAR(70)
)ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productos_20170917 
(
    producto_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    producto_nom VARCHAR(50),
    INDEX (producto_nom)
)ENGINE=INNODB;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proveedores_productos_20170917 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    proveedor_id INT, 
    producto_id INT,
    INDEX (proveedor_id,producto_id), -- para garantizar filas no repetidas
    FOREIGN KEY (proveedor_id) REFERENCES proveedores_20170917(proveedor_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (producto_id) REFERENCES productos_20170917(producto_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE

)ENGINE=INNODB;



INSERT INTO proveedores_20170917 (proveedor_nom)
    VALUES ('Proveedor 1'),('Proveedor 2'),('Proveedor 3')
;


INSERT INTO productos_20170917 (producto_nom)
    VALUES 
        ('Producto 1'),
        ('Producto 2'),
        ('Producto 3'),
        ('Producto 4'),
        ('Producto 5')

;




INSERT INTO proveedores_productos_20170917 (proveedor_id, producto_id)
    VALUES 
        (1,1),
        (1,3),
        (1,5),
        (2,2),
        (2,4),
        (2,5),
        (2,1),
        (3,1),
        (3,3),
        (3,2)
;


-- Datos iniciales sin borrar / actualizar
SELECT 
    prv.proveedor_nom, GROUP_CONCAT(pro.producto_nom SEPARATOR ',') productos
FROM proveedores_productos_20170917 pp
    INNER JOIN proveedores_20170917 prv ON pp.proveedor_id=prv.proveedor_id 
    INNER JOIN productos_20170917 pro ON pp.producto_id=pro.producto_id 
GROUP BY prv.proveedor_id;


-- Borramos Producto 1
DELETE FROM productos_20170917 
WHERE producto_id=1;


-- Al borrar Producto 1
SELECT 
    prv.proveedor_nom, GROUP_CONCAT(pro.producto_nom SEPARATOR ',') productos
FROM proveedores_productos_20170917 pp
    INNER JOIN proveedores_20170917 prv ON pp.proveedor_id=prv.proveedor_id 
    INNER JOIN productos_20170917 pro ON pp.producto_id=pro.producto_id 
GROUP BY prv.proveedor_id;



-- Actualizamos Producto 2
UPDATE productos_20170917 
SET producto_nom= 'Producto 2 actualizado' 
WHERE producto_id=2;


-- Al actualizar Producto 2
SELECT 
    prv.proveedor_nom, GROUP_CONCAT(pro.producto_nom SEPARATOR ',') productos
FROM proveedores_productos_20170917 pp
    INNER JOIN proveedores_20170917 prv ON pp.proveedor_id=prv.proveedor_id 
    INNER JOIN productos_20170917 pro ON pp.producto_id=pro.producto_id 
GROUP BY prv.proveedor_id;
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
-- Datos iniciales sin borrar / actualizar

proveedor_nom   productos
Proveedor 1     Producto 1,Producto 3,Producto 5
Proveedor 2     Producto 1,Producto 2,Producto 4,Producto 5
Proveedor 3     Producto 1,Producto 2,Producto 3


-- Al borrar Producto 1

proveedor_nom   productos
Proveedor 1     Producto 3,Producto 5
Proveedor 2     Producto 2,Producto 4,Producto 5
Proveedor 3     Producto 2,Producto 3


-- Al actualizar Producto 2

proveedor_nom   productos
Proveedor 1     Producto 3,Producto 52  Proveedor 2 Producto 2 actualizado,Producto 4,Producto 5
Proveedor 3     Producto 2 actualizado,Producto 3
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me sirvió de mucha ayuda :D

Comment: Me alegro @JeanRodríguez. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La relación conceptual entre las tablas 'producto' y 'proveedor' -para el caso de que un producto sea ofertado por uno o varios proveedores- es de muchos a muchos (N:M), es decir, un producto podría ser ofrecido por uno o varios proveedores y un proveedor podría ofrecer uno o varios productos, dicha relación se resuelve agregando una tabla en el medio, una tabla de unión, intermedia, tal como correctamente lo has indicado. Quizás el identificador de la tabla deba ser algo como: 'proveedor_producto'.

Para eliminar las filas dependientes -en la tabla de unión- puedes definir la restricción FOREIGN KEY con la regla **ON DELETE CASCADE**, te adjunto el enlace con la documentación: [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)