# ¿Qué significa CASCADE, SET NULL, RESTRICT, NO ACTION en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

He estado trabajando con tablas relacionales, pero resulta que existen 4 tipos de "acciones" cuando la fila hija es borrada o actualizada y no se qué pueda significar, aunque a todas les coloco CASCADE sin saber realmente su función.

¿Me ayudan?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está explicado [al final de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/102952/29967), lo he traducido de la documentación.

Comment: en realidad no es en PHPmyAdmin, es en MySql

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Se llaman **restricciones de integridad referencial**.

Las relaciones existentes entre distintas tablas de una base de datos MySQL que utilizan el motor de almacenamiento InnoDB pueden estar especificadas en forma de restricciones de clave externa (“Foreign Key Constraints”), de manera que la propia base de datos impida que se realicen operaciones que provocarían inconsistencias.

El comportamiento por defecto de una restricción de clave externa es impedir un cambio en la base de datos como consecuencia de una sentencia `DELETE` o `UPDATE`, si esta trajese como consecuencia un fallo de la integridad referencial.

Veremos primero en resumen las diferentes restricciones de integridad referencial,  haciendo uso de algunas imágenes para el caso de `ON DELETE`.

Las imágenes consideran dos tablas `personas` y `ciudades` relacionadas mediante la columna `ciudad_id`:

[image: DISEÑO DE TABLAS]

<sub>[Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XBNN.png) de A. Cedano para stackoverflow.es</sub>

---

### `RESTRICT`

- **`RESTRICT`**: Es el comportamiento por defecto, que impide realizar modificaciones que atentan contra la integridad referencial.

  En la imagen vemos el resultado de esta consulta:

  ```
  DELETE FROM ciudades WHERE ciudad_id=4;
  ```

  Vemos que el registro se puede borrar porque no existe registro relacionado en la tabla `personas`.

[image: RESTRICT]

<sub>[Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9yWS.png) de A. Cedano para stackoverflow.es</sub>

En cambio esta consulta:

```
    DELETE FROM ciudades WHERE ciudad_id=1;
```

Arrojaría un mensaje de error:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db`.`personas`, CONSTRAINT `personas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`ciudad_id`) REFERENCES `ciudades` (`ciudad_id`))

Porque el `DELETE` viola la restricción. Si la fila `1` de `ciudades` se borrase, las filas `1` y `4` de `personas` quedarían ***huérfanas***, o sea, sin relación en la tabla `ciudades`.

---

### `CASCADE`

- **`CASCADE`**: Borra los registros de la tabla dependiente cuando se borra el registro de la tabla principal (en una sentencia `DELETE`), o actualiza el valor de la clave secundaria cuando se actualiza el valor de la clave referenciada (en una sentencia `UPDATE`).

  En la imagen vemos el resultado de esta consulta:

  ```
  DELETE FROM ciudades WHERE ciudad_id=1;
  ```

  Aquí se borrarán en cascada `CASCADE` **todos** los registros de `personas` que tengan `ciudad_id` igual a `1`, y como es evidente, se borrará en `ciudades` la ciudad con id `1`.

[image: ON DELETE CASCADE]

<sub>[Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V8Lp.png) de A. Cedano para stackoverflow.es</sub>

---

### `SET NULL`

- **`SET NULL`**: Establece a `NULL` el valor de la clave secundaria cuando se elimina el registro en la tabla principal o se modifica el valor del campo referenciado.

  Lo que vemos en la imagen es el resultado de esta consulta:

  ```
  DELETE FROM ciudades WHERE ciudad_id=1;
  ```

  Aquí la columna `ciudad_id` de la tabla `personas` establecerá los valores a `NULL`, en todas las filas cuyo `ciudad_id` sea igual a `1`.  Y como es evidente, se borrará en `ciudades` la ciudad con id `1`.

[image: ON DELETE SET NULL]

<sub>[Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZvI4.png) de A. Cedano para stackoverflow.es</sub>

Por lo que ocurre en este caso es importante señalar que este `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personas 
(
    persona_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    persona_nom VARCHAR(70),
    ciudad_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_ciudad(ciudad_id) REFERENCES ciudades(ciudad_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL

)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Arrojará el error:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

Creo que no es difícil averiguar el por qué :)

---

### `NO ACTION`

- **`NO ACTION`**: En MySQL funciona igual que `RESTRICT`. Ver explicación más abajo.

---

### Código de prueba

Dejo aquí un demo para que podamos probar con datos reales cómo funciona cada restricción. Sólo tendremos que cambiar la configuración de la restricción en el `CREATE TABLE` poniendo las distintas posibilidades.

El ejemplo está basado en `DELETE`, pero podemos escribir y probas consultas `UPDATE` si así lo deseamos.

Este es el enlace.

> <kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/ENCX33603)**</kbd>

---

### Más sobre las restricciones

Lo que sigue está casi todo tomado de la documentación de MySQL.

Las restricciones, tanto de llaves primarias-foráneas, se indican generalmente al momento de crear la tabla (`CREATE TABLE`). Las relativas a integridad referencial hay que indicarlas explícitamente, ya que MySQL no las deduce basándose en las llaves primarias-foráneas indicadas. Si no se crean durante el `CREATE TABLE` se pueden modificar posteriormente mediante `ALTER TABLE`. La documentación explica cómo hacerlo.

Existen dos tipos de restricciones: `ON DELETE` y `ON UPDATE`. Y dentro de ellas a su vez varias posibilidades (es lo mismo para ambas).

Vamos a explicarlo con la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

Para los motores de almacenamiento que admiten claves foráneas, MySQL rechaza cualquier operación `INSERT` o `UPDATE` que intente crear un valor de clave externa en una tabla secundaria si no hay un valor de clave candidata coincidente en la tabla primaria.

Cuando una operación `UPDATE` o `DELETE` afecta a un valor de clave en la tabla principal que tiene filas coincidentes en la tabla secundaria, el resultado depende de la acción referencial especificada utilizando las subcláusulas `ON UPDATE` y `ON DELETE` de la cláusula `FOREIGN KEY`. MySQL admite cinco opciones con respecto a la acción que se va a tomar:

- `CASCADE`: Elimine o actualice la fila de la tabla principal y elimine o actualice automáticamente las filas coincidentes en la tabla secundaria. Tanto `ON DELETE CASCADE` como `ON UPDATE CASCADE` son compatibles. Entre dos tablas, no se definen varias cláusulas `ON UPDATE CASCADE` que actúan en la misma columna en la tabla primaria o en la tabla secundaria.

Nota
Las acciones de clave externa en cascada no activan activadores.

- `SET NULL`: Elimine o actualice la fila de la tabla principal y establezca la columna o columnas de clave externa en la tabla secundaria en `NULL`. Se admiten las cláusulas `ON DELETE SET NULL` y `ON UPDATE SET NULL`.

Si especifica una acción `SET NULL`, asegúrese de que no ha declarado las columnas de la tabla secundaria como `NOT NULL`.

- `RESTRICT`: Rechaza la operación de eliminación o actualización para la tabla padre. Especificar `RESTRICT` (o `NO ACTION`) es lo mismo que omitir la cláusula `ON DELETE` o `ON UPDATE`.
- `NO ACTION`: Una palabra clave del SQL estándar. En MySQL, equivalente a `RESTRICT`. El servidor MySQL rechaza la operación de eliminación o actualización para la tabla primaria si hay un valor de clave externa relacionado en la tabla referenciada. Algunos sistemas de base de datos tienen cheques diferidos, y `NO ACTION` es un cheque diferido. En MySQL, las restricciones de clave externa se comprueban inmediatamente, por lo que `NO ACTION` es igual que `RESTRICT`.
- `SET DEFAULT`: Esta acción es reconocida por el analizador de MySQL, pero tanto InnoDB como NDB rechazan las definiciones de tablas que contienen cláusulas `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` o `ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT`.

Para una `ON DELETE` o `ON UPDATE` que no se especifica, la acción predeterminada es siempre `RESTRICT`.

MySQL admite referencias de clave externa entre una columna y otra dentro de una tabla. (Una columna no puede tener una referencia de clave externa a sí misma.) En estos casos, "registros de tabla secundaria" se refiere realmente a registros dependientes dentro de la misma tabla.

Una restricción de clave externa en una columna generada almacenada no puede utilizar `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, `ON DELETE SET NULL`, `ON UPDATE SET NULL`, `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` o `ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT`.

Una restricción de clave externa no puede hacer referencia a una columna generada virtual.

Para las restricciones de InnoDB relacionadas con claves externas y columnas generadas, consulte la [Sección 14.8.1.6, "Restricciones de InnoDB y FOREIGN KEY"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: Excelente explicacion, wow, fenomenal, justamente ahora estoy asignándole RESTRICT a tablas hijas que no quiero que se vean afectadas en DELETE del padre, pero las demás tablas hijas en CASCADE si son necesarias, para que no quede información digamos "en el aire", sin ninguna razón de quedarse ahí almacenada.
muchisimas gracias A.Cedano.

Answer (score 13):

La acciones referenciales indican cómo una operación `UPDATE` o `DELETE` en la tabla padre va a afectar a las filas relacionadas de la tabla hija.  Puedes encontrar las diferencias entre las acciones en la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#idm139657013902816):

- `CASCADE`: Cuando se hace `UPDATE`/`DELETE` en la tabla padre, automáticamente se actualizarán/borrarán las filas relacionadas de la tabla hija.
- `SET NULL`: Cuando se hace `UPDATE`/`DELETE` en la tabla padre, las claves foráneas de las filas relacionadas en la tabla hija se pondrán a `NULL`. Es importante asegurarse que esos campos no tendrán la restricción de `NOT NULL` o podrás recibir errores.
- `RESTRICT`: si se intenta hacer una acción de `UPDATE`/`DELETE` en la tabla padre ésta será rechazada automáticamente.
- `NO ACTION`: Ésta es una palabra clave de SQL, en MySQL es equivalente a `RESTRICT`.

Existe un quinto valor `SET DEFAULT` que, aunque aceptado por el procesador de MySQL, puede causar problemas con InnoDB y NDB que rechazarán las tablas definidas con ese valor.

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL, solo el motor de InnoDB actualmente admite restricciones de clave externa. La sintaxis de las restricciones de clave externa en InnoDB es la siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_NAME] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name, ...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

## CASCADE :

Al actualizar / eliminar registros en la tabla primaria, actualice / elimine los registros coincidentes en la tabla secundaria al mismo tiempo

## SET NULL ：

Al actualizar / eliminar registros en la tabla principal, establezca la columna del registro coincidente en la tabla secundaria como nula [tenga en cuenta que la columna de clave externa correspondiente en la tabla secundaria no se puede establecer en NO NULO]

## NO ACTION :

Negarse a actualizar o eliminar o eliminar la tabla principal

## RESTRICT :

Negarse a actualizar o eliminar la tabla primaria

## Nota: Especificar RESTRICT o NOACTION tiene el mismo efecto que ignorar ON DELETE o ON UPDATE.