# Crear tabla con Fk

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy teniendo problemas para crear una tabla con varias Foreign key

Las tablas son las siguientes

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Autor(

nAutorID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
cNombre VARCHAR(20),
cApellidos VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_Libro(

nLibroID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
cTitulo VARCHAR(20),
nAnyoPublicacion DATE,
nEditorial INT,
CONSTRAINT fk_Editorial FOREIGN KEY(nEditorial) REFERENCES tbl_Editorial(nEditorialID)
ON DELETE SET NULL

);
```

y esta es la que me da problemas

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_LibroAutor(

nLibroID INT,
nAutorID INT,
CONSTRAINT pk_LibroAutor PRIMARY KEY(nLibroID, nAutorID),
CONSTRAINT fk_Libro FOREIGN KEY(nLibroID) REFERENCES tbl_Libro(nLibroID)
ON DELETE SET NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Autor FOREIGN KEY(nAutorID) REFERENCES tbl_Autor(nAutorID)
ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: Qué error te da? Puede haber un sinfín de problemas, pero tienes que ser más específico, porfavor :)

Comment: Por favor postea el error que te da el gestor. Porque leyendo por encima se ve bien la estructura de cada tabla...

Comment: Tienes un problema aquí, al final de las restricciones: `ON DELETE SET NULL`... porque las columnas de referencia en ambos casos no admiten nulos. En la tabla libros: `nLibroID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE`  y en la tabla autor:  `nAutorID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE`. La restricción dice que cuando se borre una fila con esa FK, establezca a `NULL` la columna con ese id en la tabla de referencia, lo cual es imposible, como comprenderás. Yo explico precisamente ese caso **[aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967)**, al hablar de `SET NULL`.