# Modificar usuario

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos con 2 tablas. Una llamada `sec_users` con los siguientes campos:

- `pk_user` `login` `pswd`

Otra tabla llamada `solicitud` con los siguientes campos:

- `pk_solicitud` `fk_usuario` `fecha`

Cada usuario puede crear una solicitud. El campo `fk_usuario` de la tabla `solicitud` es clave foránea del campo `login` de la tabla `sec_users` Bien yo creo una solicitud por ejemplo con usuario1:

```
    pk_solicitud          fk_usuario          fecha
===================     =============     ==============
       1                   usuario1          2018/04/02
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, mi problema viene cuando quiero modificar el login de usuario que en vez de usuario1, lo quiero cambiar a usuario3 y me da este error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd_vacaciones`.`solicitud`, CONSTRAINT `Usuario` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_usuario`) REFERENCES `sec_users` (`login`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Mi sentencia es la siguiente:

```
update sec_users set login='usuario3' where login = 'usuario1'
```

Alguna solución??

Comment: Por el mensaje de error: `ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`, se puede comprender que cuando actualizas el campo en `sec_users`, éste no se va a actualizar en `solicitud`. Entonces, la actualización falla porque de realizarse, habría inconsistencia de datos. La restricción para `UPDATE` debería estar definida como `ON UPDATE CASCADE` en lugar de `no action`, así, cuando actualices en una tabla, se actualizará en la otra (cascada). [Aquí puedes ver como funcionan las restricciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967), está explicado para `DELETE`, pero para `UPDATE` es lo mismo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Es cierto! no se me había ocurrido eso! Muchas gracias! Ya lo he solucionado!

Comment: Me alegro. Si me dices en qué DBMS estás trabajando podría escribir una respuesta que pueda servir como referencia para futuros usuarios.

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí, estoy trabajando con MySQL

Comment: @Xerox como los comentarios de ACedano resolvieron tu problema, lo mejor sería que marcaras su respuesta como aceptada :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## El problema

Por el mensaje de error: `ON DELETE NO ACTION` **`ON UPDATE NO ACTION`**, se puede comprender que cuando actualizas el campo en la tabla `sec_users`, éste no se va a actualizar en la tabla `solicitud`.

Entonces, la actualización falla porque de realizarse, habría inconsistencia de datos. O sea, como la columna no se actualizará a `usuario3` en la tabla `solicitud`, dicha columna seguiría siendo `usuario1` y quedaría *huérfana*, dado que su referencia cambió a `usuario3`....

## La solución

Para que los cambios de columnas relacionadas tengan efecto en sus columnas de referencia, la restricción para UPDATE debería estar definida como `ON UPDATE CASCADE` en lugar de <s>`NO ACTION`</s>. Así, cuando actualices en una tabla, se actualizará en la otra (en cascada).

Para hacer este cambio en MySQL puedes proceder del modo siguiente:

- borras la restricción actual (esto borra la restricción en sí, no las columnas ni los datos que hay en ellas)

  ```
  ALTER TABLE `solicitud` 
  DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_usuario`;
  ```
- la creas de nuevo, indicando que quieres actualizaciones en cascada

  ```
  ALTER TABLE `solicitud`  
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`fk_usuario`) REFERENCES `sec_users` (`login`) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
  ```

[Aquí puedes ver como funcionan las restricciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967), está explicado para `DELETE`, pero para `UPDATE` es lo mismo.