# Uso de ON_DELETE en Constraints

Tags: phpmyadmin

soy nuevo graduado en informática y me motiva todo esto de programacion; estoy realizando un sistema administrativo de recursos humanos para mi institución (Policia) estoy usando el yiiframework 1.1 me parece bastante practico este framework; ahora bien cree 5 tablas: funcionarios, familias, estudios, transferencias y bajas; por supuesto las ultimas 4 tablas las relacione con la tabla "funcionarios"; tengo 2 problemas es el siguiente: PRIMERO: quiero que al borrar 1 registro de la tabla "Funcionarios" me borren los registros de esa ID de las tablas Estudio, Familias y Transferencias. SEGUNDO: en el caso de la tabla "Bajas" quiero que se mantanegan la bitagora o registros permanentes; me comentaron que usando ON_DELETE llamando con Constraints,la verdad no se como hacerlo; me podrian ayudar dentro de sus posibilidades...!!!

Comment: [Aquí intenté explicarlo de forma sencilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967) con teoría, con código y con imágenes.

Comment: Lo pondre en practica para ver como me va, gracias

Answer (score 3):

Para la primera respuesta, el **`"on delete cascade"`** es para que cuando el registro de la tabla principal se borre, se eliminen las tablas hijas que tienen el "on delete cascade".

```
CREATE TABLAPRINCIPAL
(
    ID_TABLA NUMBER(3);
)
ALTER TABLE TABLAPRINCIPAL ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE1_PK PRIMARY KEY 
(ID_TABLA )  ENABLE;
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 
(
  ID_DE_TABLAPRINCIPAL NUMBER(3) 
);
**ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE1_FK1 FOREIGN KEY
(  ID_DE_TABLAPRINCIPAL )
REFERENCES TABLAPRINCIPAL
(  ID_TABLA ) ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE;**
```

El punto principal es cuando creas la llave foranea para relacionar con tu tabla principal, poner on delete cascade enable.

Para el segundo punto, lo que tienes que hacer es hacer un borrado logico, y eso solamente lo controlas con un campo en tu tabla, le puedes poner "status" donde cada que consultes, consultaras el estado del registro.

Comment: me parece bien la lógica, probare entonces, gracias

Comment: Buen dia @Alejandro, tu respuesta me sirvio perfectamente, sin embargo me lo hace para una sola tabla relacionada, es decir, cuando intento colocarle esa sintaxis a las demas tablas me produce un error de duplicidad. Error: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update

Comment: mi codigo es: ALTER TABLE estudios ADD CONSTRAINT funcionarios_id FOREIGN KEY (funcionarios_id) REFERENCES funcionarios (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE; si coloco el mismo codigo a las demas tablas: familias, historial, ubicacion me indica el error anterior

Comment: Buen dia, ya solucione lo del borrado tipo cascada gracias por sus aportes...¡¡¡ por otro lado tengo el dilema de mi segundo problema, no debo borrar registros de mi ultima tabla relacionada, como haria??

Comment: El borrado logico como tal no existe, es algo que tu logica de progrmacion debe de proveer. Para ello en las tablas que necesites borrado logico, deberas de anexar un campo, que en mi caso lo llamo "status" donde es un numerico, 1 Activo 0 Inactivo, asi cuando consultes informacion de informaicon activa, deberas de colocar "status" igual a 1.

Answer (score 0):

### REGLAS DE INTEGRIDAD REFERENCIAL

> 1. ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE. Sirve para indicar que cuando se borre o se elimine el registro de la tabla padre también se elimine
>      o modifique el registro de la tabla hija
> 2. ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL. Sirve para dar la instrucción que cuando se elimine o modifique el registro de la tabla
>      padre, se convierta a NULL ese registro en la tabla hijo
> 3. ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION. Es similar a restrict, es decir en MySQL va a impedir que tanto la acción de ON DELETE y ON
>      UPDATE se lleven a cabo
> 4. ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT Ayudan a impedir que acciones de actualización o de eliminación entre tablas vinculadas se lleve a cabo con el fin de mantener y asegurar la integridad referencial

EJEMPLO

Imagina que tengo una tabla usuarios y una tabla posts, cada post que se registra se guarda con el id del usuario en forma de llave foránea; entonces me quedaría así

```
CREATE TABLE users](
  id INT PRIAMRY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE posts(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  user_id INT NOT NULL /*ESTE campo me servirá como llave foránea*/
  CONSTRAINT fk_posts_users FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Fuente: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Buena tardes Alfredo, el detalles que estoy verificando es que mis tablas ya estan creadas, como haria para modificar y colocarle esa propiedad ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE a ellas? como seria el proceso y sistanxis

Comment: ya lo lograste hacer? @YvanOliveros

Comment: No he podido hacerlo amigo Alfredo, tambien por un poco de inexperiencia al respecto, por otro lado es q tengo las tablas creadas y la idea no es deshacer las tablas por cuanto el sistema ya esta avanzado; me disculpas mi novatada hay un refran que reza: no hay pregunta tonta sino tonto que no pregunta; me podrias explicar con ejemplos como lo hicistes; estoy trabajando con XAMPP Mysql.

Comment: si claro en un momento @YvanOliveros

Comment: pregunto la solución de @Alejandro no te sirvió?

Comment: Si amigo @Alfredo el ejemplo de Alejandro me sirvió perfectamente mil gracias; sin embargo el segundo punto nose como hacerlo: creo un campo llamado "status" donde cada que vez que consultes, consultaras el estado del registro (nose como hacerlo, osea el campo si lo creo, el sentido lógico lo entiendo pero en la practica no.).

Comment: Buen dia, ya solucione lo del borrado tipo cascada gracias por sus aportes...¡¡¡ por otro lado tengo el dilema de mi segundo problema, no debo borrar registros de mi ultima tabla relacionada, como haria??