# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Clase Respuesta

```
public class Respuesta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    private String contenido;

    private int puntos = 0; 
    private int likes = 0;
    private int dislikes = 0;

    @Cascade( CascadeType.DELETE)
    @ManyToOne
    private Usuario respuestaSuya;//Hace referencia a la respuesta del usuario

    @Cascade( CascadeType.DELETE)
    @ManyToOne
    private Post postRespuesta;//Hace referencia a la respuesta que se hace en el post
}
```

Clase Usuario

```
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String alias;

    private String contrasena;

    @Cascade( CascadeType.DELETE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="PostSuyo")
    private Collection<Post> Post;//Lista de post del usuario
}
```

Clase Post

```
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue//(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String titulo;      

    @Cascade( CascadeType.DELETE)
    @ManyToOne
    private Usuario PostSuyo;
}
```

Cuando intento borrar un `usuario` con `repoUsuario.delete(id);` recibo el siguiente error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`proyecto`.`respuesta`, CONSTRAINT `FKcs7kln9u5cvb01g50jegpnlq3`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`post_respuesta_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`))

Comment: Fijate si el registro que queres eliminar tiene relacion en otra tabla por ejemplo tenes la tablas clientes donde tenes cargado al cliente 1, dsp tenes otra tabla donde tenes productos ej id 1 detalle harina, y una tabla ventas donde pones el id del cliente y lo que compro por ejemplo cliente 1 producto 1, o sea el cliente 1 compro harina. Ahora si queres eliminar al cliente 1 y este es FK en la tabla venta no vas a poder, primero tenes que eliminar las ventas que le hiciste a este cliente para luego poder eliminarla ya que la FK no te lo permite.

Comment: Estás violando una regla de integridad referencial, porque el `DELETE` de ejecutarse crearía un registro *huérfano*, o sea, sin ninguna relación en la otra tabla. Hay varias formas de evitar esto, generalmente redefiniendo las reglas de integridad referencial, [quizá esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967), leída con calma, te ayude a entender ese (en un principio) intrincado problema de la *integridad referencial*.

Comment: Segun tu ejemplo el usuario que queres eliminar dio una respuesta a un post por lo que no podrias eliminar ese usuario porque si no esa respuesta que dio quedaria huerfana como dijo @A.Cedano (Ese link que dejo lo explica bien), para poder eliminar ese usuario tendrias que eliminar esa respuesta que dio, existe la opcion CASCADE que si eliminas un dato con un id va a y elimina todo lo relacionado a ese id, **TODO** por lo que tenes que tener cuidado y saber cuando usarla.