# Consulta MySQL con tabla intermedia

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de prácticas con MySQL y no consigo hacer la siguiente consulta:

Tengo estas tablas:

```
TP_PANTONE_COLORS

id_pantone_color (primaria)

name_pantone_color

hex_pantone_color
```

---

```
TP_COLOR_CART

id_color_cart (primaria)

name_color_cart

description

link
```

---

```
TP_PANTONE_BASE (intermedia)

id_quantity (primaria)

id_pantone_color

id_color_cart

quantity
```

---

Quiero sacar un `select` que muestre una tabla tal que así

```
NAME_PANTONE_COLOR | NAME_COLOR_CART | QUANTITY | LINK
```

De manera que luego pueda meter un `where` con la id del pantone que quiera mostrar los color_cart, estoy probando cosas con `inner join` pero no soy capaz

Esto es lo que creo que está más cerca de lograrlo (aunque creo que aún así está bastante lejos), estoy tratando de comprender bien el funcionamiento de INNER JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM tp_color_cart A INNER JOIN tp_pantone_base B ON        
A.id_color_cart = B.id_color_cart INNER JOIN tp_pantone_colors C ON  
C.id_pantone_color = B.id_pantone_color WHERE id_pantone_color=1
```

Lo que necesito es sacar los "color_cart" y su "quantity" de la tabla intermedia que tiene cada "name_pantone_color"

Comment: por favor se tan amable de agregar lo que llevas intentado aunque no te quede aún

Comment: @element Agregado :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estas buscando algo como esto.

```
SELECT 
A.name_pantone_color    AS 'NAME_PANTONE_COLOR' ,
C.name_color_cart       AS 'NAME_COLOR_CART',
B.quantity              AS 'QUANTITY',
C.link                  AS 'LINK'
FROM tp_pantone_colors A
    JOIN tp_pantone_base B  ON B.id_pantone_color=A.id_pantone_color
    JOIN tp_color_cart   C  ON B.id_color_cart=C.id_color_cart 
WHERE A.id_pantone_color=1
```

Comment: El problema es que esa consulta me devuelve solo una fila, y en la tabla tp_pantone_base hay más de un resultado con id_pantone_color=1.. En alguna de las múltiples pruebas llegué a obtener un resultado, al menos parecido, a lo que me indicas, pero no se por qué no salen todos los resultados que tienen id_pantone_color=1 que son 4 exactamente

Comment: @Dani seguramente no salen todas las filas que esperas porque en alguno de los `JOIN` no hay coincidencias. Eso es fácil de saberlo: cambia los `JOIN` de la consulta por `LEFT JOIN`, y si en efecto hay 4 filas te las traerá todas, sólo que en las columnas no coincidentes te mostrará `NULL`. Así sabrás de paso que hay algo mal en las relaciones, datos que no se está llenando correctamente. Si tus tablas son `InnoDB` es bueno que les pongas restricciones de *integridad referencial* (si quieres profundizar sobre este tema, [puedes leer aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967).

Comment: Un millón de gracias a todos, tenía un error en los datos que estaba usando de ejemplo. Al menos me ha servido para aprender bastante. Gracias a todos!