# PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 MySQL

Tags: mysql, pdo, mariadb

Estoy haciendo un Insert con la función inserttxtmovbank luego de capturar los datos de un archivo txt luego de recuperado cada dato.

```
if($upload === 1) {

 $file = fopen($ruta,"r") or die("Unable to open file!");

 fgets($file);


while(!feof($file)){

     $txt = fgets($file);

     $nro_movimiento = substr($txt,12,11);

     //convierto datos del string monto a un formato numero para subir a la 
     base de datos 
     $monto = substr($txt, 90, 26 );
     $decimales = substr($monto ,-2,2);
     $tamanocifra = strlen($monto ); 
     $tamanoentero = $tamanocifra-3;
     $entero = substr($monto,0,$tamanoentero);
     $enterowopunto = str_replace ('.' ,'' , $entero );
     $monto2 = $enterowopunto.".".$decimales;
     $mounts= number_format($monto2, 2, '.', '');
     $datefull = substr($txt,1,9);
     $day = substr($txt,0,2);
     $month = substr($txt,3,2);
     $year = substr($txt,6,4);
     $aDate = $year."/".$month."/".$day;
     $description = substr($txt,24,36);
     $type = substr($txt,23,3);
     $operador = substr($Noperardor,0,2).substr($Aoperardor,0,2);
     $status =  1;
     $movimiento=array($nro_movimiento=>array("monto"=>$mounts,
                                              "fecha"=>$aDate,
                                              "descripcion"=>$description,
                                              "tipo"=>$type, 
                                              "operador"=>$operador,
                                               "estatus"=>$status));

      //tomo del array los datos de la linea leida y lo subo a base de datos 
      //con la función inserttxtmovnbank

    insertxtmovbank($nro_movimiento, 
                    $banco, 
                    $movimiento[$nro_movimiento]["monto"], 
                    $movimiento[$nro_movimiento]["fecha"], 
                    $movimiento[$nro_movimiento]["descripcion"],
                    $movimiento[$nro_movimiento]["estatus"], 
                    $movimiento[$nro_movimiento]["tipo"]);//linea 356 
        //mencionada en el error 

 } 
 fclose($file);

}
```

Aca muestro la Función que contiene el Insert en MariaDB es el documento funciones.php

```
      function insertxtmovbank($num_movimiento, $fk_id_Banco, $fl_monto, 
      $dt_fecha_Mov,$nb_descripcionMov, $int_status, $fk_tipo_movimiento) {
   try {

        $conexion = new Conexion();
        $db       = $conexion->get_conection();
        $query    = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO movbancario (num_movimiento,                                       
                     fk_id_Banco,fl_monto,dt_fecha_Mov,nb_descripcionMov, 
                     int_status,fk_tipo_movimiento)
                      VALUES ('$num_movimiento', '$fk_id_Banco', 
                       '$fl_monto','$dt_fecha_Mov','$nb_descripcionMov'
                       ,'$int_status','$fk_tipo_movimiento')");
       $insertar = $query->execute(); //linea 88 mencionada en el error 

       $resultado = $insertar;

       return $resultado;

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {

          echo $th;
        }        
      }
```

Al hacer el Insert en la Tabla me genera el Siguiente SQLSTATE [23000]
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`addclientesasg`.`movbancario`, CONSTRAINT `movbancario_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_tipo_movimiento`) REFERENCES `tipo_movimiento` (`tipo_movimiento`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-asgmultiplex\funciones.php:88 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-asgmultiplex\funciones.php(88): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm-asgmultiplex\cargararchivo.php(356): insertxtmovbank('0000000656 ', '0105', '271.00', '2019/02/06', 'DC 0031325151 L...', 1, 'TDC') #2 {main}

Las tablas que estoy usando son movbancario que dejo la imagen a continuación[image: Tabla movbancario que es donde hago el insert]

y la tabla tipo de movimiento que muestro a continuación: [image: tabla tipo de movimiento que almacena los posibles tipos de movimiento bancarios que se relaciona con la tabla movbancario]

y Esta sería la vista relaciones de la tabla movbancario [image: Vista relaciones de movbancario]

Y aquí les dejo el diseño de la base de datos para que vean las relaciones establecidas entre las tablas. [image: Diseño de la base de Datos con las relaciones entre tablas]

Comment: El error ocurre porque tienes declarada una regla de *integridad referencial* entre la tabla **`movbancario`** usando la columna `fk_tipo_movimiento`  y la tabla  **`tipo_movimiento`**, usando la columna `tipo_movimiento`. Para decirlo en lenguaje llano, esa regla dice que todo valor que introduzcas en `fk_tipo_movimiento` debe existir en  `tipo_movimiento` de la otra tabla. Si intentas introducir por ejemplo el valor `5` y el mismo no existe en la otra tabla, tendrás el error, porque ese valor sería *huérfano* en la tabla hija (no tiene ninguna fila relacionada en la tabla padre).

Comment: El asunto de la *integridad referencial* cuesta entenderlo, sobre todo si no se tiene mucha experiencia trabajando con bases de datos. Mira si [esta respuesta con algunas explicaciones gráficas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967) arroja un poco de luz sobre cómo funciona este tipo de restricciones. Lo que intenta la *integridad referencial* es evitar que haya registros huérfanos en las tablas, o sea, que no apunten a ninguna fila relacionada en la tabla padre, porque si son tablas relacionales no tendría sentido tener un valor que supuestamente apunta a un registro que no existe.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes un error de violación de integridad, significa que estás haciendo una operación que no cumple con las reglas que has establecido entre las tablas.

En este caso, la regla que está impidiendo continuar con la operación es `movbancario_ibfk_1`, la cual hace referencia a la columna `tipo_movimiento` de la tabla `tipo_movimiento`.

Antes de insertar en base de datos, realiza un `print_r` de la operación y verifica que el valor que estás insertando en

```
INSERT INTO movbancario (num_movimiento, fk_id_Banco,fl_monto,dt_fecha_Mov,nb_descripcionMov, int_status,cfk_tipo_movimiento) 
VALUES ('$num_movimiento', '$fk_id_Banco', '$fl_monto','$dt_fecha_Mov','$nb_descripcionMov' ,'$int_status','$fk_tipo_movimiento')"
```

El valor `$fk_tipo_movimiento`existe en `tipo_movimiento.tipo_movimiento`. Ese valor, además, viene de una operación `$type = substr($txt,23,3);`, verifica que la extracción ha sido correcta.

Recuerda marcar este comentario como respuesta si soluciona tu pregunta.