# Valor AUTO_INCREMENT en base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos

tengo un AUTO_INCREMENT en una columna. **Ejemplo:** cuando elimino a maria el id AUTO_INCREMENT continua en 4 y no en 3 ¿Hay alguna manera de que no haga eso y me tome de nuevo el 3?

```
ID | NOMBRE

1  | JOSE
2  | LUIS
3  | MARIA (X Elimino a maria)
4  | TAVO
```

Comment: No, no la hay. Ni se recomienda que la haya. ¿Por qué? Por un motivo muy simple, muchas veces la columna `ID` es la que se usa como llave foránea para relacionar a `TAVO` con otras tablas. Si intentas darle a `TAVO` el `ID` de la extinta `MARIA` y hay relaciones digamos en 3 o 10 o 100 tablas de la base de datos, para tener un orden bonito tendrás que: 1. implementar un código sacado de no sé donde para mover el `ID`; 2. implementar un código para actualizar igualmente el nuevo ID de `TAVO` en las otras 100 tablas relacionadas; 3. tener desactivadas las restricciones de integridad referencial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que yo sepa no, no la hay. Ni se recomienda que la haya. ¿Por qué? Por un motivo muy simple, muchas veces la columna `ID` es la que se usa como llave foránea para relacionar a `TAVO` con otras tablas. Si intentas darle a `TAVO` el `ID` de la extinta `MARIA` y hay relaciones digamos en 3 ó 10 ó 100 tablas de la base de datos, tan solo para tener un orden bonito de 1,2,3... en tu columna autoincremental, tendrás que emprender un trabajo difícil, oscuro y peligroso que pasaría por:

1. implementar un código sacado de no sé donde para mover el `ID`;
2. implementar un código para actualizar igualmente el nuevo `ID` de `TAVO` en las otras 100 tablas relacionadas y en cada uno de los registros de esas tablas en los que `TAVO` aparezca, cambiando el `ID 4` por el `ID 3`;
3. tener desactivadas las restricciones de *integridad referencial*.

Hablando de *integridad referencial*, es un concepto que sería importante entender si vas a trabajar con bases de datos. Si la tabla que presentas está destinada a relacionarse con otras tablas lo correcto sería que declares reglas de *integridad referencial* indicando al manejador lo que debe ocurrir cuando una fila sea actualizada o eliminada.

Si esas reglas están bien, `MARIA` tendría un `ON DELETE CASCADE`, lo cual significa que al borrar a `MARIA` su `ID` se borraría de todas las tablas donde es llave foránea, para que no queden registradas en esas tablas lo que se conoce como registros *huérfanos*. Al haberse borrado `MARIA` esos registros que sólo tenían sentido de existencia porque se relacionaban con ella, debería desaparecer. De lo contrario tendrías lo que se conoce como *incosistencia de datos*.

En [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967) a la pregunta *[¿Que significa CASCADE, SET NULL, RESTRICT, NO ACTION en PHPMyAdmin?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105890/29967)* yo intenté explicar de una forma gráfica, lo que ocurre con la *integridad referencial*. Es importante entender cómo funciona si vas a trabajar con bases de datos relacionales.