# Modificar registros en tabla detalle

Tags: php, mysql

estoy en un proyecto sobre control de ordenes de trabajo que es mi tabla maestra y los trabajadores en una tabla detalle, ya puedo hacer el INSERT con este codigo enviandole el array como parametros al modelo:

```sql
for ($i = 0; $i < count($workersListDecoded);$i++ ) {
    $workOrderDetailValue = array(
              "work_detail_orderId" => $workOrderId,
              "work_detail_userId" => $workersListDecoded[$i]["id"],
              "work_detail_payment" => $workersListDecoded[$i]["workPayment"]);

$responseDetail = ModelWorks::mdlCreateWorkOrderDetails($workOrderDetailValue);
            }
```

Mi pregunta es como hacer UPDATE al detalle al editar el maestro de las ordenes de trabajo? intento hacerlo igual con el ciclo for pero solamente me toma la ultima cadena del array y el caso es cuando tenga que eliminar trabajadores. Es valido traerme el detalle de la orden almacenar en un array efectuar los cambios eliminar los registros del detalle y enviarlos de nuevo con INSERT?

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu pregunta. ¿Podrías mostrar el código del `UPDATE` y decirnos cuál es el error en sí?

Comment: El codigo del UPDATE es igual al INSERT solo que le envio los parametros al modelo y el WHERE seria el ID de la orden de trabajo para modificar pero el caso es que quiero actualizar todas las filas implicadas en el maestro en caso de tener cambios al editarla. Ejemplo Pepe Luis y Pedro estan en la orden ID 3213 pero resulta que Pepe lo cambian por Jose y eliminan a Pedro entonces como puedo hacer ese UPDATE al modelo?

Comment: Todavía no entiendo del todo, pero me parece que es mejor manejar esto a nivel de base de datos, aplicando las restricciones de integridad referencial. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967), quizá sea algo así lo que necesites, en vez de querer hacerlo tú mismo de modo manual.

Comment: Si entiendo bien al crear una orden de trabajo ya haces el insert en la tabla de detalle para esta orden de trabajo, ahora tu pregunta es que si por ejemplo se cambia un trabajador por otro o se elimina un trabajador a la orden de trabajo como deberías hacer el update / delete,  en ambos casos necesitas usar un where orderId = n and userId in (n,n,n)

Comment: @stanchacon yo crearía reglas de integridad referencial para esos casos: `ON DELETE CASCADE` y `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. No veo motivo para intentar hacer a mano algo que el manejador de base de datos haría mucho mejor que yo y con menos riesgo de error.

Comment: El punto es que ON UPDATE CASCADE no aplica en mi caso debido a que solo necesito modificar los ID de los trabajadores en el detalle ubicando la filas con el WHERE orderId = n..numero por ejemplo si sacan a 2 Pepe y Luis quedando solo Pedro con su ID como elimino a Pepe y a Luis de la tabla detalle?

Comment: Yo es que todavía no alcanzo a entender el contexto por lo que dar una respuesta definitiva se complica. Puede que en tu caso las cosas se están complicando porque quizá necesitarías otra tabla adicional que maneje las relaciones en vez de tener todo mezclado. En esa tabla cada usuario tendría su relación y cuando se elimine se borraría la fila de ese usuario mediante la restricción de integridad referencial. Este tipo de cosas son parte de los fundamentos de base de datos y, en mi opinión, no hay que querer hacer por sí mismo lo que el gestor de BD hace mejor, pues para eso existe.

Comment: Veamos otro punto de vista, tengo una tabla ventas maestro y otra ventas detalle donde la relacion es de 1:n. en la tabla detalles se guarda el ID de la factura y los ID de los productos n veces como se especifiquen en el maestro. Resulta que luego se quiere cambiar un producto por otro (UPDATE) adicionar (INSERT) o eliminar (DELETE) en una fila de la tabla maestra (no tiene ID de productos por lo tanto no puedo hacer CASCADE) no se si me doy a entender