# Dos Delete juntos en SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 Begin tran
 DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2016/12/31 23:59:59'

DELETE FROM EntradaVTP  
WHERE id in (
    SELECT id
    FROM Solicitud 
    WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion <= @DATE
)
```

Pero también tengo que eliminarlos de la tabla SalidaVTP y es justo lo mismo, hay alguna forma de unificar?  Algo como esto:

```
....
  DELETE FROM EntradaVTP   AND SalidaVTP... 
    WHERE id in (......
```

gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es posible hacerlo directamente, pero puedes guardar los registros a eliminar primero (en una tabla temporal) y luego eliminar los coincidentes en la primera tabla y luego los coincidentes con la segunda.

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2016/12/31 23:59:59'

DECLARE @TablaIDs table (id int)

INSERT INTO @TablaIDs (id)
SELECT id FROM Solicitud 
WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion <= @DATE

DELETE FROM EntradaVTP  
WHERE id in (
    SELECT ID FROM @TablaIDs 
)

DELETE FROM SalidaVTP  
WHERE id in (
    SELECT ID FROM @TablaIDs 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Se podría también con una sola consulta, de este modo:

```
DELETE t1, t2
FROM Solicitud s
      LEFT JOIN EntradaVTP t1  ON s.id = t1.id
      LEFT JOIN SalidaVTP  t2  ON s.id = t2.id
WHERE
      s.FechaCreacion <= @DATE;
```

Aquí se traen los registros de ambas tablas mediante un `LEFT JOIN` en cada una de ellas y todas las filas que vengan, tanto en  `t1` como en `t2`, cumplirán las condiciones requeridas para el `DELETE`. El `WHERE IN` en este caso no es necesario, porque los dos `LEFT JOIN` ya hacen su trabajo.

De todos modos, para evitar estar haciendo esto de forma manual (aunque sea por medio de una función), considera aplicar restricciones del tipo `ON DELETE CASCADE` en tus tablas ([aquí hay un ejemplo, explicado también gráficamente, sobre cómo funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967)), o bien considera programar un `TRIGGER` en alguna de las tablas para que borre los registros en la(s) otra(s).

> ### Advertencia
>
> Antes de hacer cualquier prueba con código de este tipo guarda una
> copia de seguridad de tus tablas.

Comment: Esta deberia ser la respuesta aceptada