# Como puedo agregar una variable que me traiga los datos de una table para insertarlos en otra sin dañar el codigo actual

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes Compañeros, mi problema es: me dieron un código en PHP el cual marca la asistencia y/o la salida de un empleado en unatabla de una base de datos, los datos del empleado están almacenados en una tabla que se llama empleados, al momento de pasar la tarjeta RFID se extraen datos de esa tabla por el numero de cédula y se insertan en otra llamada marcados, en teoría deberian extraerse: cédula, nombre y apellido de la tabla empleados pero solo inserta la cédula, esto debido a que no tengo una variable que me traiga el nombre y otra que me traiga el apellido de la Tabla Empleados para hacer un insert con esas variables e insertarlos a la tabla marcados, ya intenté de varias formas pero se queda la pantalla en banco, no hace nada o registra solo la entrada y no marca la salida. comparto mi código y espero me puedan ayudar a resolver.

El codigo del index

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
     <?php
        require("comunes/head.php");
        require("conectar.php");
        require("determinar_movimiento.php");
     ?>

     <body>
       <?php   require("comunes/nav.php"); ?>

    <header>

        <div align="center">
           <br><br>          
                <br><br>
            <form class="form-signin" action="index.php" method="POST">


            <div style="text-align:center;color:red;font-weight:900"> 
                <img style="width:300px" src="img/logo.png"/>
                <br><br>
                <?php


                        if(isset($_GET["error"]))
                              {
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo "No hay empleado registrado con esa cedula "; ?> !
                         </div>
                         <?php
                     }

                     ?>

<?php


                        if(isset($movimiento) and ($movimiento==0))
                        {
                            ?>
                             <div style="color:black">
                             <?php echo "Cedula: ".$cedula; echo "<br>"; ?>

                              <?php  echo "Correo: ".$row["correo"];  echo "<br>"; ?>    

                              <?php  echo "Nombre y Apellido: ".$row["name"];  echo " ";  echo $row["apellido"]; echo "<br>";  ?>


                               <img src="admin/empleados/fotos/<?php echo $row['foto']; ?>" class="img-rounded" width="300px" height="350px" />
                                <?php echo "<br>"; ?>
                                </div>
                          <?php echo "<br>"; ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
                              <?php echo $tipo; echo ": "; echo $hora; ?> 
                         </div>
                         <?php
                     }
                      if(isset($movimiento) and ($movimiento==1))
                        {
                            ?>
                        <div  style="color:black">
                            <?php echo "Cedula: ".$cedula; echo "<br>"; ?>
                            <?php  echo "Correo: ".$row["correo"];  echo "<br>"; ?>
                            <?php  echo "Nombre y Apellido: ".$row["name"];  echo " ";  echo $row["apellido"]; echo "<br>"; ?>
                            <img src="admin/empleados/fotos/<?php echo $row['foto']; ?>" class="img-rounded" width="300px" height="350px" />
                            <?php echo "<br>"; ?>
                        </div>
                          <?php echo "<br>"; ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                                 <?php echo $tipo; echo ": "; echo $hora; ?> 
                         </div>
                         <?php
                     }


                     ?>

                     </div>  


      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cedula" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Acerque su credencial" required="" autofocus="" />  

    </form>
  </div>

    </header>



  <?php   require("comunes/scripts.php"); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
      function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }
      //-->
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

El código de la lógica en PHP

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST["cedula"])) {

  $cedula = test_input($_POST["cedula"]);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE cedula='$cedula'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE cedula = '$cedula'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


      if($count > 0) {


 $fecha = date("Y-m-d");
 $hora = date("H:i:s");

      $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM marcados WHERE cedula = '$cedula'";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($db,$sql2);
      $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
      $par = abs($count2%2);


        require("conectar.php");


          if ($par == 0){ 

                               $tipo = "Entrada";



   $query = "INSERT INTO marcados (cedula, name, apellido, tipo, fecha) VALUES ('$cedula', '$sql3', '$apellido', '$tipo', '$fecha')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $movimiento = 0; 


   } else{ 

                                $tipo = "Salida";



 $query = "INSERT INTO marcados (cedula, name, apellido, tipo, fecha) VALUES ('$cedula', '$sql3', '$apellido', '$tipo', '$fecha')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
     $movimiento = 1; 



        } 
        } else {


         header("location: index.php?error");
      }


}

if (!isset($_POST["cedula"])) {

         echo "Acceso prohibido";
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

 ?>
```

El Archivo SQL de la tabla Marcados

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: localhost
-- Tiempo de generación: 10-03-2020 a las 23:24:48
-- Versión del servidor: 8.0.17
-- Versión de PHP: 7.3.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `zettservice`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `marcados`
--

CREATE TABLE `marcados` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` char(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellido` char(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha_hora` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `tipo` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `marcados`
--

INSERT INTO `marcados` (`id`, `cedula`, `name`, `apellido`, `tipo`, `fecha`) VALUES
(1, 1, '', '', 'Entrada', '2020-03-07'),
(2, 2, '', '', 'Entrada', '2020-03-07'),
(32, 2, '', '', 'Salida', '2020-03-09'),
(33, 2, '', '', 'Entrada', '2020-03-09'),
(60, 25, '', '1', 'Entrada', '2020-03-09'),
(61, 25, '', '1', 'Salida', '2020-03-09'),
(64, 1, '', '', 'Salida', '2020-03-09'),
(76, 1, 'Array', '', 'Entrada', '2020-03-09'),
(77, 1, 'Array', '', 'Salida', '2020-03-09'),
(78, 1, 'Array', '', 'Entrada', '2020-03-09'),
(79, 1, 'Array', '', 'Salida', '2020-03-09'),
(80, 3, '1', '', 'Salida', '2020-03-09'),
(81, 3, '1', '', 'Entrada', '2020-03-09'),
(82, 3, '1', '', 'Salida', '2020-03-09'),
(83, 1, '', '', 'Entrada', '2020-03-09'),
(84, 1, '', '', 'Salida', '2020-03-09');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `marcados`
--
ALTER TABLE `marcados`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `marcados`
--
ALTER TABLE `marcados`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=85;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

El Archivo SQL de la tabla Empleados

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: localhost
-- Tiempo de generación: 10-03-2020 a las 23:26:43
-- Versión del servidor: 8.0.17
-- Versión de PHP: 7.3.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `zettservice`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `empleados`
--

CREATE TABLE `empleados` (
  `cedula` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `matricula` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `name` char(80) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellido` char(80) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `fnacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `curp` char(18) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `rfc` char(13) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `telefono` char(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `correo` char(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `delegacion` char(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `colonia` char(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `calle` char(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `ninterior` char(5) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `nexterior` char(5) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `cp` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `departamento` char(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `puesto` char(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `fingreso` date NOT NULL,
  `contacto` char(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `cdomicilio` char(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `ctelefono` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `casatel` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `foto` char(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `empleados`
--

INSERT INTO `empleados` (`cedula`, `matricula`, `name`, `apellido`, `fnacimiento`, `curp`, `rfc`, `telefono`, `correo`, `delegacion`, `colonia`, `calle`, `ninterior`, `nexterior`, `cp`, `departamento`, `puesto`, `fingreso`, `contacto`, `cdomicilio`, `ctelefono`, `casatel`, `foto`, `status`, `date_added`) VALUES
(1, '0', 'ANGEL', 'RUIZ', '2020-01-14', 'EAAR870405UIHI', 'EAAR870408', '556809050', 'NOMADA345@HOTMAIL.COM', 'TLAHUAC', 'GRANJAS CABRERA', 'LAS PALMAS', '12', '16', 9300, 'DIRECCIÓN GENERAL', 'DESARROLLADOR', '2020-01-07', 'EDAGR PEDRAZA', 'AV SAN RAFAEL ATLIXCO 275 A', 55665565, 0, '', 2, '2020-01-07'),
(2, '1212', 'DIANA', 'hernandez', '2020-02-13', 'maja950919fndjknsw', 'WWEWEWE', '123456', 'angelmartinezjuarez065@gmail.c', 'mexico', 'referf', 'coral', '12', '12', 13270, 'DIRECCIÓN GENERAL', 'DESARROLLADOR', '2020-02-12', 'tio', 'coral', 12212, 0, '', 2, '2020-02-19'),
(3, '430', 'angel', 'hernandez', '2020-02-07', 'maja950919fndjknsw', 'WWEWEWE', '123456', 'angelmartinezjuarez065@gmail.c', 'mexico', 'fefwe', 'coral', '12', '12', 13270, 'DIRECCIÓN GENERAL', 'DESARROLLADOR', '2020-02-13', 'tios', 'coral', 12345, 0, '', 2, '2020-02-19'),
(4, '000431', 'DIANA', 'hernandez', '2020-02-14', 'maja950919fndjknsw', 'WWEWEWE', '123456', 'angelmartinezjuarez065@gmail.c', 'mexico', 'thtr', 'coral', '23', '23', 13270, 'DIRECCIÓN GENERAL', 'DESARROLLADOR', '2020-02-05', 'tios', 'coral', 12345, 0, '', 2, '2020-02-19'),
(25, '0', 'CARLOS', 'juarez', '2020-01-18', 'maja950919fndjknsw', 'jyuj4', '5521', 'angelmartinezjuarez065@gmail.c', 'mexico', '52', 'coral', '52', '542', 13270, 'SOPORTE TÉCNICO', 'TÉCNICO EN SOPORTE', '2020-01-18', 'tios', 'coral', 12345, 123456, '', 1, '2020-01-14'),
(452, '0', 'angel', 'hernandez', '2020-02-05', 'maja950919fndjknsw', 'WWEWEWE', '123456', 'angelmartinezjuarez065@gmail.c', 'mexico', 'uikyu', 'coral', '52', '4', 13270, 'DIANA', 'Checador de tiempos', '2020-02-13', 'tios', 'coral', 12345, 123456, '', 1, '2020-02-17'),
(97807, '0', 'samy', 'asd', '2020-01-08', 'sdfsdf', 'sdfsdf', 'sdf', 'dsf', 'asd', 'sad', 'sad', 'sad', 'sad', 0, 'sad', 'PO', '2020-01-15', 'CLAUDIA AZPRA ROMERO', 'AV SAN RAFAEL ATLIXCO 275 A', 55665565, 2147483647, '', 1, '2020-01-07'),
(498484, '0', 'JUAN', 'lis', '2020-01-08', 'sdfsdf', 'sdfsdf', 'sdf', 'dsf', 'asd', 'sad', 'sad', 'sad', 'sad', 0, 'Checador de tiempos', 'TÉCNICO EN SOPORTE', '2020-01-15', 'CLAUDIA AZPRA ROMERO', 'AV SAN RAFAEL ATLIXCO 275 A', 55665565, 0, '', 1, '2020-01-07'),
(9794184, '0', 'ALEJANDRA', 'juarez', '2020-02-06', 'patar123', '959595d', '123456', 'patar@gmail.com', 'mexico', 'mar', 'coral', '12', '13', 13270, 'INFORMÁTICA', 'TÉCNICO EN SOPORTE', '2020-02-01', 'tio', 'coral', 12345, 123456, '', 1, '2020-02-05'),
(151120194, '0', 'Lorena', 'Garcia Gonzales', '2020-02-12', 'DEEL041212MCLLSRA4', '20200.', '(554) 719-', 'joseluishuerta.mtz@gmail.com', 'Xochimilco', 'Ampliacion Tepepan', 'Calle 5', '8', '', 16029, '', '8', '2020-02-09', 'Jose Luis', 'Casa, Ampliacion Tepepan', 0, 0, '', 1, '2020-02-18');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `empleados`
--
ALTER TABLE `empleados`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cedula`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer se llama **redundancia de datos** o datos repetidos sin necesidad. En la tabla `marcados` basta con que insertes sólo  la `cedula`  y si necesitas los  otros datos a posteriori haces un `JOIN` con la tabla `empleados` para obtenerlos.

Comment: Entiendo pero necesito que en la tabla marcados se añadan esos datos debido a que de ahi se enviará un mensaje con los datos de esa tabla, me podrias orientar acerca del JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

Intentar meter el nombre del empleado y sus otros datos en la tabla `marcados` es un grave error de diseño que llevaría a tener datos redundantes.

Las base de datos son relacionales, significa que **por un identificador puedes unir varias tablas** y obtener todos los datos que coincidan de esas tablas.

Por tanto, si `cedula` sirve de identificador en `empleados`, con que insertes `cedula` en `marcados` ya podrás obtener todos los otros datos mediante un `JOIN`.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    e.name, 
    e.apellido,
    e.cedula,
    m.fecha_hora,
    m.tipo
FROM empleados e
    INNER JOIN marcados m ON e.cedula = m.cedula;
```

Esa consulta te traerá `name, apellido, cedula` desde la tabla **`empleados`** y al mismo tiempo `fecha_hora, tipo` desde la tabla **`marcados`** sin tener la necesidad de tener repetidos los datos de empleados en la tabla `marcados`, **por la columna `cedula` será suficiente para hacer el `JOIN` entre ambas tablas**.

Imagina que hay millones de filas en `marcados` y que tengas duplicados de `name` y las otras columnas millones de veces, sería una locura. Las bases de datos relacionales existen precisamente para evitar eso.

### PD

El concepto de **bases de datos relacional** va mucho más lejos y tiene ventajas que conviene conocer. Por ejemplo, tú puedes declarar que `cedula` sea lo que se conoce como ***llave foránea*** en `marcados` y establecer restricciones de [***integridad referencial***](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967), que servirían para mantener con facilidad datos consistentes en las tablas, evitando filas huérfanas (sin ningún dato relacionado).

Hay que conocer también las otras restricciones, como las de unicidad (que controlarían los duplicados), los índices (que acelerarían las consultas), etc.

Comment: Gracias por la orientacion compañero voy a aplicarlo

Comment: @CarlosHernandez me faltaron comas en las columnas del `SELECT`, he corregido el código, no olvides poner las comas en tus pruebas.