# Trigger no funciona correctamente SQL

Tags: sql, trigger

He creado este trigger en PHPMYADMIN

```
BEGIN

IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jugador_stats WHERE id_partido = new.id_partido AND jugador = new.jugador) > 0) THEN

DELETE FROM jugador_stats WHERE id_partido = new.id_partido AND jugador = new.jugador;

ELSE

INSERT INTO jugador_stats VALUES (new.id_partido, new.jugador, new.triples_metidos, new.tiros_2_metidos, new.tiros_libres_metidos, new.tapones, new.robos);

END IF;
END
```

La función que tiene es que en la tabla jugador_stats hay clave compuesta (id_partido y jugador (es el username)). Y si van a meter por segunda vez los datos de un jugador del partido que te borre la primera vez que se hizo y que te deje con la segunda. Pues nunca se INSERTAN los datos. Si borro el trigger si me deja, pero claro, si los vuelvo a insertar hay claves compuestas repetidas.

Comment: No entiendo por qué usas un `INSERT`... ¿no sería mejor hacer un `UPDATE` o bien poner una restricción del tipo `ON UPDATE CASCADE` (sobre esto último, [ver más detalles aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967))?

Comment: Porque en la tabla jugador_stats no hay datos. Se insertan

Comment: Ya, pero si están llamadas a ser tablas dependientes deberías resolver esto mediante llaves foráneas creando las restricciones a nivel de la tabla. Las bases de datos dan la posibilidad de usar restricciones de *integridad referencial* precisamente para evitar que montes esa lógica por tu cuenta con las limitaciones que ello implica, sin contar las situacioens erróneas en las que podrías caer. Sé que al principio eso puede sonar a chino, pero si vas a trabajar con bases de datos es uno de los fundamentos de las mismas que recomiendo que aprendas a usar. Será de gran ayuda.