# Error con Referencia constraint

Tags: sql-server

Mi error es el siguiente

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "SalidaVTP_Reabastecida1". The conflict occurred in database "PME",
>   table "dbo.SalidaVTP", column 'ReabastecidaId'.

Estoy algo perdida el que me sale mal es

```
DELETE FROM dbo.SolicitudVTP 
WHERE SolicitudVTP.id 
IN (SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE);
```

Que hago mal?

Que tengo que hacer ?? No se me ocurre nada :(

Pongo mi código completo.. T_T

```
Begin tran

DECLARE @DATE DATETIME; SET @DATE = '2016/12/31 23:59:59';
DECLARE @tablaArqueoID TABLE (ArqueoID int) INSERT INTO @tablaArqueoID (ArqueoID) SELECT Id from Arqueo WHERE Arqueo.Fecha >@DATE --or Arqueo.Fecha is null
DELETE FROM dbo.Preasiento WHERE Preasiento.SolicitudId IN (SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE); 
DELETE FROM dbo.Evento  WHERE Evento.SolicitudId IN (SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE); 
DELETE FROM dbo.SalidaCB WHERE SalidaCB.Id in (SELECT Solicitud.Id FROM dbo.Solicitud Where Solicitud.FechaCreacion >@DATE );
DELETE FROM dbo.SalidaVia WHERE SalidaVia.Id in (SELECT Solicitud.Id FROM dbo.Solicitud Where Solicitud.FechaCreacion >@DATE );
Delete From dbo.Preasiento Where Fecha > @DATE
DELETE FROM dbo.Arqueo    WHERE Arqueo.Id IN (SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE); 
DELETE FROM Arqueo WHERE Fecha > @DATE 
DELETE EV FROM EntradaVTP EV JOIN SalidaVTP SV ON EV.SolicitudSalidaId = SV.Id JOIN Solicitud S ON SV.Id = S.Id WHERE S.FechaCreacion > @DATE
DELETE SV FROM SalidaVTP SV JOIN Solicitud S ON SV.Id = S.Id WHERE S.FechaCreacion > @DATE
DELETE SVV FROM SalidaVTP SVV JOIN SolicitudVTP SVT ON SVT.id = SVV.ReabastecidaId JOIN Solicitud S ON SVV.Id = S.Id WHERE S.FechaCreacion > @DATE
DELETE CB FROM SalidaCB CB JOIN Solicitud S ON CB.Id = S.Id WHERE S.FechaCreacion > @DATE
DELETE FROM SolicitudFondoCB WHERE SolicitudFondoCB.Id in ( SELECT Solicitud.Id From dbo.Solicitud Where Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE)
DELETE FROM dbo.SolicitudVia  WHERE Id IN ( SELECT Solicitud.Id From dbo.Solicitud Where Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE)
DELETE FROM dbo.SolicitudVTP  WHERE SolicitudVTP.id IN(SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE); 
DELETE FROM dbo.IncrementoFO  WHERE IncrementoFO.id IN(SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE); 
DELETE FROM dbo.EntregaManual  WHERE MomentoEntrega > @DATE; 
DELETE FROM dbo.DisminucionFO  WHERE DisminucionFO.id IN(SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE); 
DELETE FROM dbo.DevolucionEC  WHERE DevolucionEC.id IN(SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE); 
DELETE DF FROM DesgloseFacial DF JOIN Arqueo A ON DF.Id = A.DesgloseFacialId JOIN CajaBase CB ON A.CajaBaseId = CB.Id WHERE A.Fecha > @DATE
DELETE FROM dbo.VTP  WHERE VTP.CajaBaseId IN(SELECT Solicitud.CajaBaseId FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE); 
DELETE FROM dbo.DevolucionCE  WHERE DevolucionCE.id IN(SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE);
DELETE FROM dbo.Traspaso      WHERE Traspaso.id IN(SELECT Solicitud.id FROM dbo.Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion > @DATE); 
DELETE FROM dbo.Solicitud  WHERE FechaCreacion > @DATE; 
DELETE FROM GerenciasCalendario WHERE Dia > @DATE  
DELETE FROM GerenciasCalendario WHERE FModificacion > @DATE
DELETE FROM dbo.AlbaranRecepcion WHERE Fecha > @DATE  
DELETE FROM AlbaranEntrega WHERE Fecha > @DATE  


rollback tran
```

Comment: Puede ser que al momento de traer la lista de los ids, alguno de ellos no este en la tabla SalidaVTP?

Comment: Voy a poner todo mi Script.. ^^

Comment: El problema es que tienes registros en la tabla SalidaVTP cuya clave externa es un campo de la tabla SolicitudVTP.
No podrás eliminar los campos de SolicitudVTP sin eliminar primero los de SalidaVTP que toman como referencia el campo ReabastecidaId.

Comment: Te está saltando un error que hace referencia a la *integridad referencial*, explicado llanamente son restricciones de la BD para evitar que haya registros huérfanos en las tablas relacionadas. Es decir, si tu `DELETE` se ejecutase alguna fila de `SolicitudVTP` que está relacionada con registros de otra tabla dejaría a aquellos registros huérfanos. Este tipo de situaciones es mejor resolverlas en la misma definición de la tabla. Si en dos tablas relacionadas tú pones por ejemplo una restricción del tipo `ON DELETE CASCADE`, cuando se borre una fila relacionada el registro de la otra tabla..[+]

Comment: ...[+] se borrará en cascada (de ahí `CASCADE`). Hay restricciones tanto para cuando se borran registros (`ON DELETE`)  como para cuando se actualizan (`ON UPDATE`)  y hay varios  tipos de restricciones de IR que conviene conocer. Son uno de los fundamentos básicos de BD y facilitan enormemente el trabajo. Creo que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967), aunque es para MySQL, puede ayudarte a entender al menos un poco de que va. Luego tendrás que aplicarlo en SQL Server, pero el principio es el mismo.

Comment: el problema es que no se como hacerlo,.. se que falta algo, pero no se que tabla ni el que..  ya he estado tocando mirando y no sé a que se refiere.. :(

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: `The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "SalidaVTP_Reabastecida1". The conflict occurred in database "PME", table "dbo.SalidaVTP", column 'ReabastecidaId'.` te dice que ese `DELETE` está violando una restricción de integridad referencial en la tabla `SalidaVTP`. Tienes que revisar cómo están definidas las relaciones entre esas dos tablas, revisando por ejemplo el `CREATE TABLE` de ambas. Allí verás qué restricciones tienen. Lo más probable es lo que te comentaba antes: que el `DELETE` deje alguna fila huérfana en la otra tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con este código, lo importante sería que entiendas lo que hace y luego lo implementes, en pocas palabras busca todas las tablas que hacen referencia con un Fk al Pk de la tabla que indiques, y luego crea y ejecuta los scripts para eliminarlos, finalmente elimina el ID de la tabla princial.

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[spBorrado](
@ID int
) as
declare  
 @SQLScriptSelect nvarchar(max)
,@SQLScriptDelete nvarchar(max);

if object_id('tempdb..#tempFksID') is not null drop table #tempFksID;

select 
    cast(f.name as varchar(255)) as foreign_key_name
    , cast(c.name as varchar(255)) as foreign_table
    , cast(fc.name as varchar(255)) as foreign_column
    , cast(p.name as varchar(255)) as parent_table
    , cast(rc.name as varchar(255)) as parent_column
    , SQLSriptDelete = N'delete from '+SCHEMA_NAME(c.schema_id)+'.'+cast(c.name as varchar(255))+' where ID = '+CAST(@ID as varchar(100))
    , SQLSriptSelect = N'select * from '+SCHEMA_NAME(c.schema_id)+'.'+cast(c.name as varchar(255))+' where ID = '+CAST(@ID as varchar(100))
INTO #tempFksID
from  sysobjects f
inner join sys.objects c on f.parent_obj = c.object_id
inner join sysreferences r on f.id = r.constid
inner join sysobjects p on r.rkeyid = p.id
inner join syscolumns rc on r.rkeyid = rc.id and r.rkey1 = rc.colid
inner join syscolumns fc on r.fkeyid = fc.id and r.fkey1 = fc.colid
where f.type = 'F' and fc.name = 'ID' and p.name = 'Solicitud'

SELECT @SQLScriptDelete = STUFF((
        SELECT CHAR(10) + SQLSriptDelete
        FROM #tempFksID
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
FROM #tempFksID

SELECT @SQLScriptSelect = STUFF((
        SELECT CHAR(10) +SQLSriptSelect
        FROM #tempFksID
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
FROM #tempFksID

--  execute(@SQLScriptSelect)   
execute(@SQLScriptDelete)

delete from dbo.Solicitud where ID = @ID
```