# Primary key -> foreign key con delete set null

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

mi pregunta es la siguiente, dentro de la tabla sucursal tengo la primary key cod_sucursal  y en propiedad tengo ese mismo campo como foreign key y me piden que al borrarlo que se ponga nulo. La cuestion es que al ser primary key no se puede poner null. `

```
create table Persona(
DNI         char(9),
nome        varchar(30)     not null,
enderezo    varchar(100)    not null,
telefono    char(9)         not null,
empleado    bit             not null,
cliente     bit             not null,
propietario bit             not null,
nss         char(11)        null,

Constraint PK_persona Primary key (DNI)
);

go

create table Sucursal(  
cod_sucursal    char(4),
enderezo        varchar(100)    not null,
telefono        char(9)         not null,

Constraint PK_Sucursal Primary key (cod_sucursal)

);

go

create table Propiedad(
cod_propiedad   char(4),
enderezo        varchar(100)    not null,
m2              int             not null,
num_cuartos     tinyint         not null,
num_baños       tinyint         not null,
tipo            char(1)         not null,
data_alta       date            not null,
info_vexetacion varchar(200)    null,
cortes          bit             null,
terraza         bit             null,
distancia_playa int             null,
vistas_mar      bit             null,
cod_sucursal    char(4)         not null,
DNI             char(9)         not null,

Constraint PK_Propiedade Primary key (cod_propiedad),

Constraint FK_Propiedad_Sucursal Foreign key (cod_sucursal) references Sucursal(cod_sucursal)
    on update cascade on delete set null,
Constraint FK_Propiedad_Propietario Foreign key (DNI) references Persona (DNI)
)`
```

tal y como yo lo veo no hay ninguna manera de que acepte el valor nulo, por lo tanto no podría ser posible eso. En resumen, hay alguna manera de que esta llave foranea pueda ser on delete set null, o es imposible ya que es primary key? Muchas gracias por la atencion!!

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa, las llaves foráneas generalmente no son llaves primarias. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967) y los diferentes ejemplos, quizá te ayude a aclarar conceptos.

Comment: las propiedades se registran en las sucursales, y queremos saber en que sucursal se registró cada propiedad, de ahi que tenga que llevar cod_sucursal en propiedad para identificar en sucursal se dio de alta. La pregunta ya la modifique para que fuese mas facil su entendimiento. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Yo intuyo que lo que está mal planteado es tu modelo de datos. `Sucursal` debería ser una entidad en sí misma, no tendría por qué borrarse cuando se borre un registro de `Propiedad`. Imagina que haya otras filas que apunten también a esa sucursal que se borraría, sería un desastre. Creo que debes re-pensar tu modelo de datos, no le veo ninguna lógica a lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: sucursal ya es una entidad, pero al ponerla como foreing key si la sucursal se borra, en propiedad apareceria null

Comment: Lo lógico sería quitar el `not null` a la columna `cod_sucursal` en la tabla `Propiedad` y **en esa misma tabla** poner la restricción `ON DELETE SET NULL`, así, cuando un registro sea borrado en la tabla `Sucursal` el valor en `Propiedad` adquirirá el valor `NULL`. Tú estás pensando la cosa al revés, queriendo poner la restricción en la tabla `Sucursal`. Si lees los ejemplos del enlace en mi primer comentario quizá entiendas mejor lo que quiero decir.