# MySQL: Eliminar fila de una tabla y a la vez eliminar la que está relacionada a su clave foránea

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

estoy tratando de eliminar datos de dos tablas pero no puedo lograrlo. Tengo una tabla llamada chofer que contiene una llave primaria llamada idchofer y la cual la llevo como llave foránea a otra tabla llamada camión. Mi idea era eliminar la fila camión donde la llave foránea sea igual que la de id chofer y, eliminar a la vez, la fila chofer donde se aloje esa idchofer.
Mis intentos han sido en vano por estoy acudiendo a ustedes :)
Gracias de ante mano.

```
mysql> select * from chofer;
+----------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| idchofer | nombre    | segundo_nombre | apellidos |
+----------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
|        1 | sad       |                | asd       |
|        2 | alejandro | sdf            | aaa       |
+----------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from camion;
+----------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
| idcamion | placa | marca | modelo | idchofer |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
|        1 | asd   | asd   | asd    |        1 |
|        2 | sdf   | sdf   | sdf    |        2 |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete chofer,camion
    -> from chofer,camion
    -> where chofer.idchofer=camion.idchofer
    -> and camion.idchofer=2;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ingsoft`.`camion`, CONSTRAINT `fk_camion_chofer1` FOREIGN KEY (`idchofer`) REFERENCES `chofer` (`idchofer`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Que significa CASCADE, SET NULL, RESTRICT, NO ACTION en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105890/que-significa-cascade-set-null-restrict-no-action-en-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente es mucho más sencillo.

Si a la hora de crear la base de datos configuraste correctamente las identidades referenciales bastaría con ejecutar el comando delete, que lo que hace es borrar en la tabla que le indicas y todo lo relacionado en otras tablas relacionales.

En caso de que no configurases correctamente las relaciones en la base de datos, podrías utilizar la siguiente query para actualizar.

```
ALTER TABLE `camion`  
ADD CONSTRAINT `chofer` 
FOREIGN KEY (`idchofer`) REFERENCES `chofer` (`idchofer`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Una vez hecho eso solo tendrás que eliminar una fila de chofer y automaticamente se eliminará su camion asignado.

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono :).