# ¿Qué ventajas tiene vincular tablas con claves foráneas a no hacerlo?

Tags: base-de-datos

Yo aprendí que siempre las tablas deben estar relacionadas, pero en el proyecto al que llegué a trabajar están todas las tablas sueltas y funciona todo bien. Entonces me surgió esa duda.

Adjunto imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no utilizas claves foráneas y borrases una persona por ejemplo la persona con id=1, tendrias en gustos entradas con idPersona=1 que no existen, perdiendo la integridad referencial. Por lo que tendrías que asegurarte de que siempre que borres una persona se borren sus gustos relacionados, esto hecho idealmente en una transacción. Si lo haces con claves foráneas te puedes beneficiar de los borrados, actualizaciones, etc en cascada, por lo que si borras una persona automáticamente se borran sus gustos asociados. Cuanto más complejas sean las relaciones, más te pueden ayudar las claves foráneas

Comment: Verdad, había olvidado eso. Por cierto ¿sabes si afecta a la rapidez de las consultas?

Comment: [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967) he tratado de explicar con ejemplos prácticos la importancia de la *integridad referencial*. Si las relaciones no están definidas, tendrás que garantizar por ti mismo a través de código que no haya registros huérfanos en las tablas al momento de insertar, borrar o actualizar datos. En algunas respuestas de SO en inglés se afirma que ayudan también en la rapidez de las consultas, puede que sea así (o no), lo cierto es que aquello que ayuda a optimizar las consultas  son los índices y tener un buen diseño de datos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[La respuesta @SquareCog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/83393/5587982) a la pregunta *[What's wrong with foreign keys? - ¿Qué hay de malo con las claves foráneas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83147/5587982)* responde con argumentos verificables a tu pregunta. La dejo aquí traducida y la marco como Wiki de comunidad por si alguien quiere aportar más ventajas o desventajas.

### Razones para usar llaves foráneas:

- no tendrás filas huérfanas
- puedes obtener un buen comportamiento "al eliminar en cascada", limpiando automáticamente las tablas
- conocer las relaciones entre las tablas en la base de datos ayuda al Optimizador a planificar sus consultas para una ejecución más eficiente, ya que puede obtener mejores estimaciones sobre la cardinalidad de unión.
- las llaves foráneas (FK) dan una pista bastante grande sobre qué estadísticas son más importantes para recopilar en la base de datos, lo que a su vez conduce a un mejor rendimiento
- permiten todo tipo de soporte autogenerado: los ORM pueden generarse por sí mismos, las herramientas de visualización podrán crear diseños de esquemas agradables para ti, etc.
- alguien nuevo en el proyecto entrará en el flujo de cosas más rápido ya que de lo contrario las relaciones implícitas se documentan explícitamente

### Razones para no usar llaves foráneas:

- harán que la base de datos trabaje más en cada operación CRUD<sup>1</sup> porque tiene que verificar la consistencia de las llaves foráneas (FK). Esto puede tener un gran costo si hay mucha rotación.
- al hacer cumplir las relaciones, las llaves foráneas (FK) especifican un orden en el que se deben agregar / eliminar los elementos, lo que puede llevar a que la base de datos se niegue a hacer lo que deseas. (De acuerdo, en tales casos, lo que estarás tratando de hacer es crear una fila huérfana, y eso no suele ser algo bueno). Esto es especialmente doloroso cuando estás realizando grandes actualizaciones por lotes, y cargas una tabla antes que otra, con la segunda tabla creando un estado consistente (pero ¿deberías estar haciendo ese tipo de cosas si existe la posibilidad de que la segunda carga falle y si la base de datos ahora es inconsistente?).
- a veces sabes de antemano que tus datos estarán sucios, lo aceptas y quieres que la base de datos lo acepte
- simplemente, estás siendo vago :-)

---

1. CRUD son las iniciales de Create, Read, Update, Delete relativas a la creación, lectura, actualización y borrado de filas en las tablas.