# Como eliminar los datos de todas las tablas a la vez en sql que tienen FOREIGN KEY y por lo tanto no me es permitido

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito eliminar los datos de todas las tablas al mismo tiempo,  pero estas al tener **foreign key** no me lo permite, claro que si eliminar los datos de todas las tablas al mismo tiempo es imposible cualquier ayuda es bien bienvenida.
Estas son las tablas que utilizo:

```
CREATE table estudio(
    id_estudio varchar(6) not null PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    pais varchar(30) not null
);

CREATE TABLE actor(
    id_actor varchar(6) not null primary key,
    nombre_actor varchar(40) not null,
    pais_actor varchar(40) not null,
    sexo varchar(1) not null,
    fecha_nac date not null,
    comision REAL
);

CREATE TABLE pelicula(
    id_pelicula varchar(6) not null PRIMARY KEY,
    titulo varchar(100) not null,
    anno varchar(4) not null,
    duracion time not null,
    costoproduccion REAL NOT null,
    ganancia REAL not null,
    id_estudio varchar(6) not null,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_estudio) REFERENCES estudio(id_estudio));

CREATE table elenco( 
   id_actor varchar(6) not null, 
   id_pelicula varchar(6) not null, 
   papel varchar(40) not null, 
   salario real not null, 
   FOREIGN KEY(id_actor) REFERENCES actor(id_actor), 
   FOREIGN KEY(id_pelicula) REFERENCES pelicula(id_pelicula));
```

Comment: En la definición de las foreign keys, tienes que agregar la opción on delete cascade. [on delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Así se encarga el motor de borrar las filas. También puedes echar un ojo a on update cascade

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa CASCADE, SET NULL, RESTRICT, NO ACTION en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105890/qu%c3%a9-significa-cascade-set-null-restrict-no-action-en-mysql)

Comment: @Javifer2 No estoy de acuerdo en que se **tiene** que declarar una llave foránea con cascada para los borrados. Por algo la cláusula es opcional en el _SQL_. Se **podría**, si se quiere y conviene, si, pero no tiene por qué ser así.

Comment: @jachguate. Correcto lo que dices, pero es una de las posibles soluciones, a este inconveniente. Quizá el comentario, parece aseverar, (no era el objetivo), cuando la intención era indicar una posible solución.

Answer (score 2):

Quiero comenzar diciendo que la idea de las llaves foráneas es justamente esa:

De manera declarativa, prevenir que haya información inconsistente en la base de datos.

La llave foránea, a menos que sea declarada de otra forma, será **restrictiva**, lo que significa que, como en este caso, no puedes eliminar un registro que está relacionado con información que existe en otra tabla, por ejemplo, un encabezado de factura, mientras esa factura tenga detalles, o en tu caso particular, no puedes eliminar un actor mientras este tenga películas.

Dicho esto, dado que *necesitas* eliminar la información, hay varias técnicas que puedes seguir para hacer este borrado, entre ellas:

### Eliminar la información en orden

Esto significa, eliminar primero los detalles y luego los encabezados. En otras palabras, cuando tienes una relación de *uno a muchos*, primero eliminas los datos de la tabla con cardinalidad *muchos* y luego los de la tabla con cardinalidad *uno*.

En tu caso, que el modelo es sencillo, esto debiera funcionar:

```
delete from elenco;
delete from pelicula;
delete from actor;
delete from estudio;
```

En modelos más complejos, vas tomando las tablas que no tienen ninguna tabla *detalle* que las relacione, y recorriendo el modelo *hacia arriba*, para ir limpiando. Escribir una rutina de borrado, de esta manera, es sencillo si tienes un buen conocimiento del modelo de datos.

Esto puede complicarse un poco cuando hay relaciones circulares o jerárquicas entre tablas. En estos casos, generalmente es necesario hacer un `update` en una de las tablas para *romper* la relación, por ejemplo establecer el valor de la(s) columna(s) que forman la relación a `null` y luego proceder a eliminar.

Esto tiene la ventaja que no tienes que cambiar el modelo, ni re-escribir o adaptar el código de las aplicaciones que funcionan sobre él.

### Declarar una regla de cascada para la llave foránea

Esto consiste en *propagar* el borrado. Es decir, si se elimina un registro de una tabla, que tiene registros *hijos* en otra(s) tabla(s) el borrado será *propagado* a estas tablas y estos registros también serán eliminados.

Esto es muy conveniente, pero debes estar consciente que, declarar tus llaves foráneas de esta manera, puede provocar pérdidas de información, tanto si un usuario es el que está realizando una acción sin medir las consecuencias (esos usuarios existen, créeme), como por un error de programación (el típico `delete` sin `where` del que hacemos tantos memes).

Esto se hace desde el momento de crear el modelo de datos, por ejemplo la creación de tu tabla `pelicula` quedaría algo así:

```
create table pelicula(
      id_pelicula varchar(6) not null primary key
    , otros campos...
    , foreign key (id_estudio) references estudio(id_estudio) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

He dejado en mayúsculas la cláusula `ON DELETE` al final de la declaración de la llave foránea.

También puedes eliminar las llaves foráneas si ya existen, y re-crearlas con la opción de cascada.

Si todas las relaciones tuviesen cascada, bastaría con borrar la(s) tabla(s) raíz del modelo, aquellas de las que parte toda la información, que son las que no tienen llaves foráneas hacia otras tablas, en tu caso:

```
delete from estudio
delete from actor
```

Luego de esto, todo el esquema estará *limpio*.

### Declarar una regla `set null` para la llave foránea

Otra opción, es declarar una regla `ON DELETE SET NULL` para la llave foránea.

Esto, lo que hace es que, cada vez que se borra un registro que tiene *hijos*, los campos que componen la relación se establecen a `null` en la tabla que se relaciona, durante la operación de borrado, de manera que se rompe la relación.

En este caso, la sentencia de creación de la tabla quedaría algo como:

```
create table pelicula(
      id_pelicula varchar(6) not null primary key
    , otros campos...
    , id_estudio varchar(6)
    , foreign key (id_estudio) references estudio(id_estudio) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Acá, tienes que borrar la información de todas las tablas, pero puedes hacerlo en cualquier orden, ya que la existencia de una referencia no impedirá que se borre:

```
delete from actor;
delete from estudio
delete from pelicula;
delete from elenco;
```

Debiera resultar obvio que para que esto funcione, los campos que relacionan las tablas no debieran tener el atributo `not null`, lo cual podría implicar cambios en la forma de hacer los `join` (`outer` en lugar de `inner`) y la programación que está realizada sobre los datos de estas tablas.

### Modelos híbridos:

Hay ocasiones en las que, por una razón o por otra, no es posible tener todos los borrados en *cascada*. Hay motores, por ejemplo, que solo permiten que se declare una llave en cascada para cada tabla, o que validan que un mismo borrado no pueda llegar a una tabla por dos vías distintas. En esos casos, declaras `on delete cascade` donde el motor lo permite, y luego tu rutina de borrado va haciéndolo en orden, por todas las tablas que no tienen borrado en cascada, comenzando por las tablas detalle hasta llegar a las tablas raíz.

### Mi recomendación:

Si tienes experiencia y tomas todo en cuenta, lo más cómodo es tener borrados en cascada.

Si no, es mejor tener un modelo más restrictivo y realizar los borrados en orden.

Hay ocasiones, la mayoría de las veces, en que trabajas con modelos heredados y la programación está realizada con un modelo restrictivo en mente. Un programador cauto pensaría dos veces antes de poner borrados en cascada en el modelo subyacente de una aplicación que está escrita para un modelo restrictivo.