# Update con múltiples tablas en php

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos como puedo realizar un UPDATE a campos que traigo de dos tablas me explico: Tengo una tabla llamada oficina y otra tabla llamada proveedor, dichas tablas están relacionadas; donde traigo todos los datos de la oficina y el nombre del proveedor a la que pertenece, me actualiza los datos de la oficina pero no se como podría actualizar los datos del proveedor en ese UPDATE teniendo en cuenta que el nombre lo tengo en la tabla proveedor , a continuación dejo el fragmento de código.

Código UPDATE

```
$query_insert = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE
oficina SET nombreOficina = '$nombreOficina',
ciudad = '$ciudad', encargado = '$encargado', ntarjeta =
'$ntarjeta');
```

PDTA: No se como llamar el campo proveedor para poder realizar dicha operación.

Comment: Sobre qué base de datos? Asumimos que MySQL? Procura siempre indicarlo, pues la respuesta puede variar dependiendo de esto

Comment: @Alfabravo Correcto es con MySQL

Comment: Podrias colocar la relacion entre esas tablas? no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer

Comment: @ernestojimenez  tengo una tabla llamada proveedor, una tabla llamada oficina , donde de proveedor obtengo el nombre del proveedor, de la tabla oficina obtengo la información de la oficina que se ve en el Update , el usuario admin puede editar la información por si se equivoca y le ingreso mal el nombre del proveedor o esa x oficina no pertenece al proveedor entonces puede cambiar el nombre , el inconveniente es que el nombre del proveedor esta en la tabla proveedor , el me actualiza la información de oficina solamente.

Comment: Entonces, hay una tabla donde agrupas oficina y proveedor, Si X proveedor es agrupado en X oficina por error, el administrador debe cambiarlo cierto?

Comment: O acaso ```encargado ``` representa el campo relacionado en proveedor? por eso seria bueno que colocaras una imagen para identificar las tablas y su relacion

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no resuelves esto definiendo las [*restricciones de integridad referencial*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967) adecuadas? De este modo las tablas se mantendrían normalizadas sin necesidad de ninguna intervención por programación.