# Actualizar id multitabla con inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Hola amigos estoy tratando de actualizar un id en 2 tablas , en empleados es la llave primaria que se llama ID, y en solicitud se llama ID_EMPLEADO llave foranea , quiero actualizar el id en ambas tablas pero me sale un error por ambas estas relacionadas, a continuación relaciono el error y el código que trato de actualizar, vale aclarar que si hago esa misma sentencia actualizando nombre de empleados y código de la tabla solicitud si actualizan, únicamente presento el problema al tratar de actualizar los id.

```js
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`konecta`.`solicitud`, CONSTRAINT `solicitud_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_EMPLEADO`) REFERENCES `empleado` (`ID`))

update solicitud INNER JOIN empleado on solicitud.ID_EMPLEADO=empleado.ID SET solicitud.ID_EMPLEADO=10358,empleado.ID=10358 WHERE solicitud.ID_EMPLEADO=8974
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa CASCADE, SET NULL, RESTRICT, NO ACTION en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105890/qu%c3%a9-significa-cascade-set-null-restrict-no-action-en-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo la llave primaria no deberías actualizarla, por eso es que en muchas ocasiones se crea de llave primaria un campo llamado id autoincrementadle que no representa ninguna información del registro.

En resumen te aconsejo que si ese campo puede cambiar es mejor que no lo uses como llave foránea.

Comment: Complementando lo de diego, el id debe ser un identificador unico, por lo que una vez este generado no se debe cambiar, porque si tu referencias en algun otro lado ese ID (Sea para una consulta o para realizar alguna accion donde necesites llamarlo) al actualizarlo se te van a desencadenar mas errores