# Cómo obtener la variable dentro de una funcion PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo una clase "Roles.php" que tiene una función insertar:

```
public function insertRol($datos)
{
    global $pdo;
    try {
        $id_fd = 1;
        // return $datos;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO roles (id_fd, descripcion, nombre_rol)
                                                                            VALUES (:id_fd, :descripcion, :nombre_rol)");

        $stmt->bindValue(':id_fd', $id_fd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':descripcion', $datos['detalle'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':nombre_rol', $datos['rol'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $ultima_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Necesito tomar la variable $ultima_id y enviarla a mi otra clase llamada ArchivosRoles.php donde tengo otra función insertar:

```
public function insertArchivosRoles($dato)
        {
            global $pdo;
            try {
                $ultId = 1;
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO archivos_roles ( id_rol, nombre_archivo)
                                                                                    VALUES (:id_rol, :nombre_archivo)");

                $stmt->bindValue(':id_rol', $ultId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(':nombre_archivo', $dato, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();

                if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                        return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

En el valor de id_rol necesito insertar la variable $ultima_id de la otra clase en la primera función. Help me please.

Comment: En el primer método tendrías que poner un `return $ultima_id;` y recuperarlo en la segunda función. En tu caso yo manejaría esto mediante un TRIGGER o, mejor aún, definiendo restricciones de integridad referencial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si analizas tu código podrás ver que `insertRol()` estás retornando `true` o `false`, en ningún caso retornas el valor de la variable `$ultima_id` que es el que necesitas para hacer la inserción en `insertArchivosRoles()`.

Por otro lado, dado que has establecido que retorne `false` en caso de no filas afectadas, deberás verificar ese estado cuando recibas la llamada a `insertRol()`. También, si quieres evitar que el código se rompa, puedes retornar `false` en la parte que captura las excepciones. De ese modo tienes un criterio de seguimiento: si retorna `false` no hubo inserción y en consecuencia haces lo que hayas contemplado para esos casos, de lo contrario hubo inserción y haces lo que hayas contemplado en ese caso. Así el código queda integrado más fácilmente a tu política de manejo de errores.

Así debería funcionar:

#### `Roles.php`

```
public function insertRol($datos)
{
    global $pdo;
    try {
        $id_fd = 1;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO roles (id_fd, descripcion, nombre_rol)
                                                                            VALUES (:id_fd, :descripcion, :nombre_rol)");

        $stmt->bindValue(':id_fd', $id_fd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':descripcion', $datos['detalle'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':nombre_rol', $datos['rol'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        #Abreviamos código

        return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ?  $pdo->lastInsertId() : false;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage()); #Esto lo puedes quitar si quieres
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

#### `ArchivosRoles.php`

```
 function insertArchivosRoles($dato)
 {
            global $pdo;
            try {
                #Si no existe instancia de la clase Rol en el contexto la creas
                $mRol=new Rol(...parametros si es preciso...);
                #Verificamos que la llamada no devuelva false
                if ( $ultId = $mRol->insertRol($datos) ) {
                  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO archivos_roles ( id_rol, nombre_archivo)
                  VALUES (:id_rol, :nombre_archivo)");

                  $stmt->bindValue(':id_rol', $ultId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $stmt->bindValue(':nombre_archivo', $dato, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $stmt->execute();

                  if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                          return true;
                  } else {
                      return false;
                  }
                  
                } else {
                  #Aquí la llamada a insertRol() habrá devuelto false, hacer lo que necesites o
                  return false;
                }
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
                return false;
            }
}
```

---

#### Otra solución posible a nivel de SGBD

Este tipo de situaciones pueden resolverse también a nivel de la base de datos, sin necesidad de programar código PHP. Podrías declarar un disparador (TRIGGER) que haría la inserción en la tabla `archivos_roles` de cada nuevo registro que se inserte en la tabla `roles`. Si te interesa explorar esta posibilidad [aquí tienes un tutorial introductorio sobre los disparadores de tipo `AFTER INSERT`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/), que es lo que necesitarías para este caso.

Convendría que revises también el tema de las restricciones de *integridad referencial* (ver *[¿Qué significa CASCADE, SET NULL, RESTRICT, NO ACTION en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105890/29967)*), que podrían ayudarte a mantener la integridad de las tablas en casos de `UPDATE` o `DELETE`.