# no puedo borrar datos de un formulario que esta asosiado a otros ID php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

al borrar un Id de un trabajador  y presionar el boton de Eliminar me arroja esto

Error en query: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`reloj_control`.`permisos`, CONSTRAINT `permisos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Rut`) REFERENCES `trabajadores` (`Rut`)) DELETE FROM trabajadores WHERE ID_Trabajadores = 5

creo que la consulta esta mal pongo una imagen de la tabla trabajadores
[image: esta es la tabla]

```
introducir el código aquí
        public function eliminar(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli(Config::BBDD_HOST, Config::BBDD_USUARIO, Config::BBDD_CLAVE, Config::BBDD_NOMBRE);
       $sql = "DELETE FROM trabajadores WHERE ID_Trabajadores = " . $this->ID_Trabajadores;
       //Ejecuta la query
        if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
            printf("Error en query: %s\n", $mysqli->error . " " . $sql);
       }
       $mysqli->close();
   }
```

Comment: Te arroja ese error porque en la tabla hay definida una restricción de *integridad referencial*, la cual impide que haya registros huérfanos, que es lo que ocurriría precisamente si el `DELETE` tiene éxito: otra(s) fila(s) en otra(s) tablas relacionadas con la que quieres borrar, quedaría(n) huérfana(s) ([revisa esta respuesta para más detalles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo lo que tienes que hacer es entrar a la tabla trabajadores y luego a Estructura, luego te vas a vista de relaciones. Ahi revisas que tu llave foranea tenga ON DELETE CASCADE y ON UPDATE CASCADE. Te esta diciendo que el campo Rut tiene una llave foranea apuntando a otra tabla y por eso no te deja borrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]