# Constraint KEY y constraint foreign key

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, constraints

tengo una pequeña duda con respecto a una base de datos que me han pasado para trabajar con ella. Tengo ver encontrar sus errores y resolverlos de alguna forma, pero he visto algo que me hace dudar con respecto a un par de `constraints` que he visto:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employee_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hire_date` date NOT NULL,
  `job_id` int NOT NULL,
  `salary` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `manager_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`),
  KEY `EMP_DEPT_FK` (`department_id`),
  KEY `EMP_JOB_FK` (`job_id`),
  KEY `EMP_MANAGER_FK` (`manager_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `EMP_DEPT_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`department_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `EMP_JOB_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`job_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `EMP_MANAGER_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employee_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`job_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`department_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employee_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=207 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Como se puede ver hay 3 `KEY` para los campos nombrados como id, los cuales serían claves ajenas con el `FOREIGN KEY`, eso lo tengo claro, PERO lo tienen dos veces, y esto es lo que me escama.

¿Está bien esa forma de hacerlo? ¿Alguien me puede explicar algo de teoría sobre esto concretamente? Porque no lo encuentro por ningún sitio.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Las tres restricciones que mencionas serían redundantes, deberías dejar una por cada relación, decidiendo si debes definir o no reglas de integridad referencial que apliquen en cada caso, lo digo porque en algunas hay reglas de integridad referencial definidas y en otras no. Para comprender el sentido de las reglas de integridad referencial puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967).

Comment: Otra cosa que suena rara son los tres `KEY` por separado, quizá lo que necesites ahí se un índice único compuesto, el cual evitaría que haya varias filas con los mismos valores para esas tres columnas. Eso es sólo una intuición, dado que no conozco el contexto. De ser así, deberías cambiar los tres `KEY` por uno solo como este más o menos: `UNIQUE KEY UK_employees (department_id, job_id, manager_id)`

Comment: Uf, muchísimas gracias. No entendía el por qué había 3 y si se trataba de un error de redundancia o algo. Gracias. Lo de las KEY por separado tampoco lo sabía, lo echaré un vistazo. Muchas gracias.