# Error de sintaxis que desconozco

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente codigo en mysql

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS veterinario;
create database veterinario;
use veterinario;
create table clientes (
        dni varchar(9) PRIMARY KEY,
        nombre varchar(50),
        direccion varchar(60)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
create table mascotas (
        codigo integer PRIMARY KEY,
        nombre varchar(50),
        raza varchar(50),
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY cliente varchar(9) REFERENCES clientes(dni) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPD>
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Me da la siguiente salida

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,004 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0,000 sec)

Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,007 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 10 in file: '/home/alumno/veterinario.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(9) REFERENCES clientes(dni) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGI...' at line 5
```

Si alguien me puede decir que esta mal y explicarme un poco ya que es mi primera vez lo agradeceria muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Esto `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPD>` en tu penúltima línea, es erróneo, supongo que habrás querido decir **`ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Despues de buscar en esta pagina: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/ gracias a @Antonio he llegado al siguiente codigo:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS veterinario;
create database veterinario;
use veterinario;
create table clientes (
        dni varchar(9) PRIMARY KEY,
        nombre varchar(50),
        direccion varchar(60)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
create table mascotas (
        codigo integer PRIMARY KEY,
        nombre varchar(50),
        raza varchar(50),
        cliente varchar(9),
        CONSTRAINT `fk_clientes_dni`
          FOREIGN KEY (cliente) REFERENCES clientes (dni)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

El problema era que a la hora de definir cliente en la tabla mascotas no se definia correctamente osea que esto:

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY cliente varchar(9) REFERENCES clientes(dni) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPD>
```

quedaria asi definiendo la clave cliente antes del constraint

```
cliente varchar(9),
        CONSTRAINT `fk_clientes_dni`
          FOREIGN KEY (cliente) REFERENCES clientes (dni)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

despues el nombre de la clave foranea habria que haberlo indicado

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_clientes_dni`
```

por lo demas todo estaba bien quitando que faltaban parentesis y un espacio por lo que la linea quedaria asi

```
FOREIGN KEY (cliente) REFERENCES clientes (dni)
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué `ON UPDATE RESTRICT`?

Comment: Guau no conocia esa pagina web muchas gracias si conoces alguna pagina mas de interes que contenga documentacion ponmela por aqui porfavor
Gracias

Comment: Este codigo no me ha funcionado he estado leyendo de la pagina que me has enviado y al final he llegado al siguiente codigo que si me funciona lo dejo por aqui

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada, sólo falta cambiar `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` por **`ON UPDATE CASCADE`**.

Comment: Por las dudas te comento: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: No he usado openai en esta respuesta, he cogido su respuesta original y la he corregido con la documentación, no entiendo el negativo, veo que estamos nerviosos

Comment: Todavía estoy intentando buscar el sentido a la pregunta y respuesta por el mismo usuario, en cualquier caso si está resuelto, perfecto.

Comment: ahora si bro esta perfecto no se quien te ha dado el downvote no te lo mereces te doy la respuesta correcta gracias

Answer (score 1):

Despues de buscar en esta pagina: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/ gracias a @techdobycon he llegado al siguiente codigo:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS veterinario;
create database veterinario;
use veterinario;
create table clientes (
        dni varchar(9) PRIMARY KEY,
        nombre varchar(50),
        direccion varchar(60)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
create table mascotas (
        codigo integer PRIMARY KEY,
        nombre varchar(50),
        raza varchar(50),
        cliente varchar(9),
        CONSTRAINT `fk_clientes_dni`
          FOREIGN KEY (cliente) REFERENCES clientes (dni)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

El problema era que a la hora de definir cliente en la tabla mascotas no se definia correctamente osea que esto:

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY cliente varchar(9) REFERENCES clientes(dni) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPD>
```

quedaria asi definiendo la clave cliente antes del constraint

```
 cliente varchar(9),
        CONSTRAINT `fk_clientes_dni`
          FOREIGN KEY (cliente) REFERENCES clientes (dni)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

despues el nombre de la clave foranea habria que haberlo indicado

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_clientes_dni`
```

por lo demas todo estaba bien quitando que faltaban parentesis y un espacio por lo que la linea quedaria asi

```
FOREIGN KEY (cliente) REFERENCES clientes (dni)
```

Las sugerencias son 100% bienvenidas muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Y por qué la opción RESTRICT no te funciona pero CASCADE sí? Qué estabas probando y cómo? La sintaxis de ambos casos es correcta, pero dices "no me funciona" y eso a los demás no le dice absolutamente nada.

Comment: Yo queria q al actualizar la clave primaria de la tabla clientes en la tabla mascotas se actualizase por eso puse la opcion cascade y no la de restrict porque esa no me permite el cambio
No me funcionaba creo que porque si te das cuenta en la parte de la tabla mascotas en mi codigo (que he copiado de un ejemplo de la pagina que he indicado) es distinto y igual la sintaxis no estaba correcta por eso

Comment: Hola Anthony, en vez de poner una respuesta casi idéntica a la de @techdobycon considera valorar su esfuerzo por ayudarte, aceptando su respuesta y votándola positivamente, indicándole que cambie el `RESTRICT` por `CASCADE`, y es que, para el caso que nos ocupa (el error en sí) lo de `CASCADE`o `RESTRICT` es lo de menos (para profundizar en ese aspecto, te recomiendo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967)), tu error era que el código se comía la definición final, como te indiqué en mi comentario.

Comment: Ok sin problema pero en esta parte: cliente varchar(9), CONSTRAINT `fk_clientes_dni` FOREIGN KEY (cliente) REFERENCES clientes (dni) ON DELETE CASCADEON UPDATE CASCADE creo que la suya no es correcta del todo porque ademas de lo que dices tu en la parte de cliente varchar(9) el no lo indica antes del CONSTRAINT y por eso no funciona

Comment: Ok entiendo, había otro error con respecto a la definición de la columna `cliente`

Comment: Exacto si quieres edito su respuesta sin problemas

Comment: Pero ni uno ni otro explicáis nada de eso en las respuestas, son, en ese sentido, malas respuestas ambas. Cuando se responde conviene explicar cuál ha sido el error y cómo se corrige. Futuros usuarios podrían tener un problema similar y leyendo respuestas como la tuya o la otra no logran entender en qué han fallado.

Comment: Ok voy a hacer una respuesta completa

Comment: Hecho indicame que te parece

Comment: no entiendo porque volviste a reescribir la respuesta que te dieron....