# Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

disculpen que los moleste pero tengo este código en sqlite3 para generar una serie de tablas, ejecute en consola en primer lugar PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; para activar las restricciones, el problema es que al querer insertar lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO alumnos_profesores (nombre, apellido, dni, fecha, telefono, mail, actividad, id_ba, id_div, id_cur, id_cut, id_tur) VALUES ('Jose', 'Flores', 22585741, '11/08/1997', '3537324471', 'josef@hotmail.com', 'a', 1, 1, 1, 1, 2);
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

y no se que estoy haciendo mal ya que en realidad lo que pretendo es poder borrar en cascada los datos de alumnos_profesores, barrio, localidad por un lado... y por otro quiero eliminar división curso y turno por medio de las tablas intermedias div_curso y curso_tur .... no se si están mal hechas las relaciones o las claves foráneas... necesito una mano para que me ubiquen con este tema gracias... saludos

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3

conexion = sqlite3.connect('escuela_ok.db')

# ------------ Tablas de union --------------------

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mat_nota (
    id_mat INTEGER,
    id_nota INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_mat, id_nota),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_mat) REFERENCES materias(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_nota) REFERENCES notas(id));""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS div_curso (
    id_div INTEGER,
    id_cur INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_div, id_cur),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_div) REFERENCES division(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_cur) REFERENCES curso(id));""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS curso_tur ( 
    id_cut INTEGER,
    id_tur INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_cut, id_tur),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_cut) REFERENCES curso(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_tur) REFERENCES turno(id));""")

# ------------ Datos de personales --------------------

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alumnos_profesores (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    nombre  TEXT,
    apellido TEXT,
    dni INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    fecha TEXT,
    telefono TEXT,
    mail TEXT,
    actividad TEXT,
    id_ba INTEGER,
    id_div INTEGER,
    id_cur INTEGER,
    id_cut INTEGER,
    id_tur INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_ba) REFERENCES barrio(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_div, id_cur) REFERENCES div_curso(id_div, id_cur) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_cut, id_tur) REFERENCES curso_tur(id_cut, id_tur) ON DELETE CASCADE
    );""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS preceptores (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    usuario TEXT,
    clave TEXT,
    conf_clave TEXT,
    nombre TEXT,
    apellido TEXT,
    dni INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    fecha TEXT,
    telefono TEXT,
    mail TEXT, 
    id_ba INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_ba) REFERENCES barrio(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);""")

# ------------ Datos de ubicacion --------------------

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS barrio (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    calle TEXT,
    barrio TEXT,
    id_loc INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_loc) REFERENCES localidad(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS localidad(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    localidad TEXT,
    CP INTEGER);""")

# ------------ Datos de Cursado --------------------

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS materias (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    asignatura TEXT,
    id_curso INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_curso) REFERENCES curso(id));""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notas (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    calific INTEGER(2));""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS division (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    seccion TEXT
    );""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS curso (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    anio TEXT
    );""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS turno (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    mt TEXT);""")



conexion.close()
```

Comment: Las llaves foráneas de esa tabla son hacia `div_curso(id_div, id_cur)` y `curso_tur(id_cut, id_tur)`, por tanto en esas tablas deben existir los registros correspondientes. en `div_curso`, `id_div = 1, id_cur = 1` y en `curso_tur`, `id_cut = 1, id_tur = 2`. Si alguno de esos registros no existe, va a fallar con el mensaje de error que estás viendo.

Comment: Hola que tal, gracias por responder, si, he cargado en esas tablas los correspondientes registros y la falla sigue igual...

Comment: No había observado el fk a `barrio`. Ese registro también tiene que existir (1).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa CASCADE, SET NULL, RESTRICT, NO ACTION en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105890/qu%c3%a9-significa-cascade-set-null-restrict-no-action-en-mysql)