# Establecer un dato como clave foránea en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Algo esta mal en mi sintaxis o en mi BDD cuando quiero añadir el dato email como clave foranea de una tabla. ¿Que es lo que esta mal?

El objetivo que la clave primaria "Email" de la tabla "login", sea la clave foranea en la tabla form ,cuya clave primaria deberia se Id_form.

Sentencia:

```
ALTER TABLE `form`
FOREIGN KEY (`fkemail`) 
REFERENCES `login` (`email`);
```

Base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) podrás ver que la sintaxis de `ALTER TABLE` es la siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

Te está faltando el `ADD`.

Así debería funcionar:

```
ALTER TABLE `form`
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (`fkemail`) 
    REFERENCES `login` (`email`);
```

Las condiciones para que esto funcione son:

1. Que las tablas estén en `InnoDB`. Es importante tenerlo en cuenta, porque si las tablas están en `MyISAM` quizá el `ALTER TABLE` no genere error, pero tus tablas NO estarán sometidas a las restricciones de llave foráneas que estás creyendo declarar, [tal y como afirma el Manual de Referencia al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html):

> For storage engines that do not support foreign keys (such as
> `MyISAM`), MySQL Server parses and ignores foreign key specifications.
>
> ---
>
> Para los motores de almacenamiento que no admiten claves externas
> (como `MyISAM`), MySQL Server analiza e ignora las especificaciones de
> claves externas.

2. Que las columnas relacionadas sean del mismo tipo
3. Que la columna `email` en `login` sea llave primaria o que sea única.

---

**Post-Data**:

Si no quieres que se apliquen las restricciones de integridad referencial por defecto para `ON UPDATE` y `ON DELETE`, deberías definirlas explícitamente.

Para comprender mejor cómo funcionan las restricciones de integridad referencial, puedes consultar [**esta respuesta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967) a la pregunta: *[¿Qué significa CASCADE, SET NULL, RESTRICT, NO ACTION en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105890/29967)*

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Funciono correctamente.

Comment: @Roxy012 me alegro. Cuando puedas, revisa lo de la integridad referencial y asegúrate de que las tablas están en `InnoDB`, he agregado la advertencia del MR al respecto. Si tus tablas están en `MyISAM` el `ALTER TABLE` no dará error, pero las llaves foráneas serán ignoradas, así como las restricciones de integridad referencial que definas en ellas.

Comment: ok muchas gracias