# Update en campo de una tabla

Tags: mysql

tengo una base de datos con la tabla tipo_contrato y los suiguientes campos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo otra tabla contrato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TIPO_CONTRATO ES FK DE CONTRATO.. y el problema esta que cuando le cambio los precios en la tabla tipo_contrato me cambia tambien los precios de los registros guardados en la tabla CONTRATO. (Necesito que los registros ya cargados queden con los precios anteriores).

Muchas gracias, trabajo con php,js,jquery y MySQL.

Comment: Eso ocurre porque tienes declarada en la tabla una restricción de integridad referencial. Si no quieres que eso ocurra, debes quitar dicha restricción. Cabe decir que, salvo excepciones, este sería el comportamiento normal. Si quieres otra cosa, entonces quizá esa columna no debe ser llave foránea en la otra tabla. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967) para más detalles sobre la *integridad referencial*.

Comment: @A.Cedano no hay suficiente contexto para decir que esto es sobre php ... hasta que se indique si esta usando algun ORM para la gestion de la base de datos desde php y como esta declarando las entidades... paso a eliminar etiquetas mal usadas...

Comment: @A.Cedano incluso parece ser una pregunta repetida del mismo usuario: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/612219/315134

Comment: No entiendo. Dices que cambian los precios en la tabla CONTRATO, pero en la tabla CONTRATO que nos muestras no hay campos de precios.

Comment: No entiendo la tabla `Contrato` no tiene un campo precio, porque dices que te lo cambia?? no estarás haciendo un joín a la tabla `tipo_contrato` para mostrar los precios?