# Relacion Identifying Vs No-Identifying

Tags: mysql

Antes que nada, les comento que ya he leído varias preguntas similares con respuestas "técnicas" que parecen C&P. Lo que necesito es un ejemplo claro. La normalizacion es 3NF.

En este proyecto, en el panel administrativo, se tiene que crear ciudades y zonas y cada zona tiene que pertenecer a una ciudad. También crear hoteles y asignarlos en las zonas correspondieres, y por ultimo crear alias para cada hotel en particular, ya que las personas llaman al mismo hotel con diferentes nombres. Las tablas hotels y hotels_alias son para llenar un input autocomplet.

El calculo del precio se realiza según el servicio (estándar, privado y VIP) dependiendo de la zona y según la cantidad de pasajeros y la temporada, aun no creo la lógica ni las tablas para calcular el precio por pasajeros y temporada, por eso no aparecen en el diagrama de abajo.

Una buena explicación me parece esta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships

Sin embargo me surgen algunas dudas.
[image: Ejemplo 1]

hotels_alias no puede existir sin la table hotels que a su vez no puede existir sin la tabla zones y esta a su vez no existe sin cities. Ya que una Ciudad se divide en muchas zonas, los hoteles pertenecen a estas zonas, zonas que forman parte de una ciudad, y los alias de los hoteles pertenecen a un hotel y no pueden existir si no existe un hotel.

Hasta aquí queda claro que cities es una entidad fuerte o padre y zones, hotels y hotels_alias son entidades débiles o hijos.

En el diagrama EER pueden ver que tiene una relación identifying. La primera pregunta es ¿Es correcto que a pesar de ser entidades débiles o hijas tengan su propio ID? y ¿Que este ID sea PK y NN y AI? En algunos ejemplos, estas entidades hijas o débiles no tienen su propio ID, por lo tanto, su PK se forma de dos FK de las tablas relacionadas como en una relación N:N (zones_has_servicees).

Si en realidad las tablas débiles o hijas no tienen que tener su propio ID por que deben ser capaces de identificarse por su tabla fuerte o padre, ¿Entonces como seria capaz de actualizar o eliminar una zona, o un hotel o un hotel alias?

```
DELETE FROM zones WHERE name = 'nombre a borrar'
```

Es correcta la forma anterior? Tendría que crearle un index a la columna name? Que ventajas, si es que las hay, tendría hacerlo con name en lugar de su propio ID? Es correcto que una tabla débil o hija que tenga su propio ID y crear una PK compuesta con este ID y el ID de su tabla padre? Tiene alguna función este tipo de relaciones o es solo para motores como InnoDB y poder realiza un ON DELETE CASCADE?

Que pasa si tengo dos zonas con al mismo nombre? por ejemplo: Zona Hotelera, que tanto las ciudades de Cancun como Tulum tienen esa zona. Para realziar un DELETE seria?:

```
DELETE FROM zones WHERE name = 'nombre a borrar' AND cities_id = ID
```

Entendiendo lo que es un entidad padre y una hija entonces por que WordPress crea relaciones como la de abajo donde se puede ver que utiliza una relacion debil con wp_postmeta y wp_posts. Se supone que no puede existir un wp_postmeta sin un wp_posts, correcto? Hace lo mismo con comments y users.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lei tu pregunta por un par de minutos. Y no entiendo bien cuales son tus dudas, porque hay muchas preguntas, pero no termino de entender tu duda en si. Si tu modelo relacional anda, cual es el problema? no entiendo pq dices que hotel no puede existir sin zona. Todo depende de tu sistema. Y pq decis que no pueden tener su propio ID? que tiene que ver el ID con las relaciones? puedes ser mucho mas claro en lo que preguntas, pq desgraciadamente como esta en este momento, tu pregunta (aunque bien redactada y buena), se basa en opiniones.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias. Lo que no entiendo es que si al crear un entidad débil esta deba de carecer de un propio ID, ya que en ejemplos que he visto, no tienen ID propio, sino que su PK compuesta se forma de los ID de sus tablas padre. Si contara con ID propio seria ya una tabla padre. Y pues todas las preguntas que hice, son las dudas que tengo. Se que el modelo es funcional, pero queria saber si hay alguna forma de hacerlo mejor.

Comment: Una ciudad puede tener más de un hotel en la misma zona, ¿se podría identificar un hotel sólo con la ciudad y la zona en la que está? No. Necesitarías un atributo que lo identifique, y ese atributo podría ser único, NN AI, etc. Hay una [pregunta relacionada/parecida a ésta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/84599/250) que te puede interesar también.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a empezar a contestar tus dudas de a poco, y vamos a ir completando la respuesta.

### TL/DR

Las relaciones dependen mucho de lo que se quiera construir y cuál es el sistema. Y las relaciones son más que todo teóricas y llevadas a la práctica como convenga.

### Explicación

Empecemos con tu ejemplo sobre las tablas de wordpress. Las tablas meta que ves allí, son tablas hijas pero son solamente tablas creadas para guardar flags sobre la tablas padres. Esto es para evitar crear columnas infinitamente sobre las tablas padres. No es que no pueden existir sin el padre, es que se usan para otra cosa.

Por ejemplo, imagínate que sobre un usuario, se quieren guardar datos como la edad (ten en cuenta que es un ejemplo), se podría guardar en la tabla principal (agregando una columna edad), o sobre la tabla meta (un meta_key edad y su valor). Lo que hace esta tabla es evitar agregar columnas por cada nuevo atributo que se quiera mostrar. Además en este caso permite que los plug in guarden sus propios datos creando sus propias keys.

¿Entonces, es una tabla débil? teóricamente sí, pero prácticamente es la misma tabla, solo que tiene un uso para facilitar el agregado de información y evitar la modificación del esquema indiscriminadamente.

### Tus tablas

Las relaciones débiles se ven en un esquema particionado de tu tabla. Una relación débil entre dos tablas, no implica que esa tabla sea débil. Es más, dentro del sistema, una tabla débil puede ser una tabla fuerte para otra porción de la relación.

Ten en cuenta, que la tabla hoteles, no puede existir si no existe la tabla zonas. Pero, si separas la tabla hoteles, y solo miraras hotels y hotels_alias, la tabla hoteles es fuerte.

Desde hace un tiempo, en la práctica, se dejaron de llevar las claves compuestas a las tablas relacionados y se usan claves en las propias tablas. 
Fíjate un ejemplo práctico.

El hotel A esta ubicado en la Zona 1, el hotel B también está ubicado en la zona 1. Por alguna cuestión estética, la ciudad acaba de dividir la Zona 1 en Zonas 11 y 12. Y tu hotel A, ahora está en la zona 11, y el B en la 12. Fíjate que penalizaste mal tus tablas en este momento. Uno de los hoteles, va a cambiar una de sus claves foráneas si o si (la otra se salva, basta con cambiar la identificación de la zona). Con tu modelo, está penalizando un update en cascada. Que no dice nada, por que tu sistema es un ABM, no un datawarehouse (en un datawarehouse no es mala idea copiar claves de un lado a otro, pero eso es otro tema distinto).

¿Entonces, porque no dejar que tu hotel tenga su propia clave? Imagínate que quieres modificar los datos de un hotel en particular, como dijo Alvaro. No vas a poder identificarlo, a menos que sepas de que hotel hablas, y eso solo se sabe con la clave propia del hotel.

Por ejemplo fíjate que llevar la clave ciudad a todos lados no tiene ningún sentido, no aporta nada.

Como otro ejemplo, la tabla zone_has_service, no tiene id. Por lo tanto, cuando quieras modificar algo (si ya se, es una tabla de link, pero a veces las cosas hay que modificarlas), vas a tener que pasar varios valores...

Las relaciones dependen del modelo que quieras construir, y como lo vayas a manejar. Simplificar el modelo por una cuestión de accesos y tablas no es nada malo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación. La realidad es que soy autodidacta y en las expectaciones técnicas no siempre te dan el ejemplo de un caso practico o como tu dices, que depende de como se vaya a manejar. Gracias