# Campo int auto_increment como primary key

Tags: mysql, autoincremento

Tengo una tabla de usuarios en MySQL con varios campos, entre ellos el nombre de usuario (una cadena de caracteres) que es un `unique key`. A la hora de indexar con `primary key` tengo 2 opciones: usar el campo de los nombres de usuario o usar un nuevo campo `int` `auto_increment`. Por un lado los `int` al ser más cortos que las cadenas de caracteres se analizan más rápidamente, pero por otro lado aumentaría el peso de la tabla con un campo adicional. ¿Cuál sería la mejor solución?

También tengo una tabla con nombres de empresas (únicamente los nombres, sin ningún otro campo) a la cual también quiero aplicarle la pregunta anterior.

Comment: Ests pregunta está basada en opiniones y hace un tiempo que ya se hizo, en la cual hay respuestas que pueden guiarte. Puedes verla en el siguiente [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84599/qu%C3%A9-campo-elegir-para-la-clave-primaria)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Realmente era lo que necesitaba. Aunque nunca había oído hablar de los términos clave subrogada y clave natural. Incluso explican las ventajas e incovenientes de cada caso. Muy bueno la verdad.

Comment: Nada que agradecer, estamos para ayudarnos. Me alegro que te haya servido :)